# NetBeans can't run package.json on a Maven web application

Tags: maven, netbeans, npm, netbeans-8

Using NetBeans 8.2, I've created a new Maven web application. I have placed a working `package.json` file inside the `Web Pages` folder so its path is:

> C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\src\main\webapp\package.json

I left click on the `package.json`file and click the `npm install` option. I was then greeted by these errors/warnings:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "install"
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Nick\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp No license field.
Done.
```

I noticed NetBeans attempted to look for the *package.json* file at the wrong place:

> C:\Users\Nick\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\package.json'

And I can't seem to figure out how to tell the IDE where to look for it.

When I go to *Project Properties* → *JavaScript Libraries* → *npm*, I get an empty view with :

> package.json not found

How can I set up NetBeans to see that 'package.json' and run it? It worked fine when I tried using it in an HTML5 project, but I need npm support for a Java web application project.

Comment: I second this question. Seems like Netbeans wants user to split HTML5 projects from Java ones?

Comment: If I place (create) package.json in the project root folder, it seems to work: downloads libraries and dependencies etc; however I have no idea how to refer these js files from project's htmls, jsps and views

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution outside the the builtin IDE mechanics. I used the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to setup a local npm repository for my project.

Than instead of using the `npm install` option given by the IDE, I used Maven to define a goal, and run it using [`nbactions.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163994/what-is-nbactions-xml-used-for).

1. To install the plugin, edit your `pom.xml` file (snippet [from here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installation)), add the plugin descriptor and the execution that will download and install npm inside your repository:

   ```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Installs node + npm in your repo -->
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                ...
   ```
2. I've appended this code to the one above. It's an execution that runs `npm install` (snippet [found here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#running-npm)):

   ```
        ....
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>

            <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>

            <configuration>
                <!-- optional: The default argument is actually
                "install", so unless you need to run some other npm command,
                you can remove this whole <configuration> section.
                -->
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </plugin>
   ```
3. Create a `package.json` file (in the same directory where your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) is) and start putting stuff into it ([example](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/frontend-maven-plugin/src/it/example%20project/package.json))
4. I've added a reference to the `npm install` goal inside `nbactions.xml`. I've gave it a display name of `npm-install`

   ```
    </actions>
        ...
        <action>
            <actionName>CUSTOM-npm-install</actionName>
            <displayName>npm-install</displayName>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </action>
    </actions>
   ```
5. Then, right click on the Project (from the projects view) -> Run Maven -> npm-install

[image]

The plugin will then run and install a `package.json` and a Node.js runtime in a separate directory that won't be bundled with your project, you can edit it there and rerun the goal.