# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, npm-package

I've got an **ApolloServer** project that's giving me trouble, so I thought I might update it and ran into issues when using the latest Babel. My "index.js" is:

```
require('dotenv').config()
import {startServer} from './server'
startServer()
```

And when I run it I get the error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

First I tried doing things to convince TPTB* that this was a module (with no success). So I changed the "**import**" to a "**require**" and this worked.

But now I have about two dozen "**imports**" in other files giving me the same error.

*I'm sure the root of my problem is that I'm not even sure what's complaining about the issue. I sort of assumed it was Babel 7 (since I'm coming from Babel 6 and I had to change the presets) but I'm not 100% sure.

Most of what I've found for solutions don't seem to apply to straight Node. Like this one here:

*[ES6 module Import giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier/47633417#47633417)*

Says it was resolved by adding "type=module" but this would typically go in the HTML, of which I have none. I've also tried using my project's old presets:

```json
"presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
"plugins": []
```

But that gets me another error: "Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions."

Here are the dependencies I started with:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
  "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.12",
  "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
  "apollo-server": "^2.9.6",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
```

Comment: Hi, having the same problem right now. Could you also share your dependencies? Maybe even a diff before and after your update. I could check against mine to see if we can find similar packages which might cause the trouble.

Comment: I just replaced all the "imports" with "requires" and all is well now. Dumb but it wasn't worth the effort to figure it out right now. I will update the original with dependencies, though. If you get any leads, I'll check them out against my original code.

Comment: CommonJS syntax (require and module.exports) was the original format for node and webpack also supports it, but ES6 module syntax (export, import) is the newer way and now node and webpack support it. I read that node supports import now but so many tutorials show require for pure node stuff that it's likely better to use that syntax for node.

Comment: Hm, interesting, that preset only sets the {allowJs: true} setting. Same I also (already) added to the TS compilerOptions. Maybe you want to have a look into this. edit: omg, in case you actually use TS? ... what a config hell.

Comment: I used a package called package called `esm`  to write the code in es6. https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm

Comment: Please refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611980/2941150

Comment: `"type":"module"` doesn't solve my problem, and there are over a hundred of `imports`. Syntax of `require` is diff from `imports`, not an easy replace. Can you give an example of how `imports` is replaced by `requires`?

Comment: The Powers That Be: A (mildly) comic way of saying "I don't know where this is being decided."

Comment: Something *seems* to be missing at the end (after `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",`). Can you make it clearer? Either why nothing is actually missing or adding the missing part (including "`}`").

Comment: I cannot, alas. I remember the issue, and I remember getting around it in a really cheesy way, but I do not think I can recreate it now.

Comment: I had the same issue the last couple of days ... not a type:module issue ... not a config issue ... the issue was coming from the : cluster.fork().  (npm cluster module)
I have no problem with the "master" instance but the children were "broken". as I'm in a dev environement... I don't care about clustring.

Answer (score 778, accepted):

Verify that you have the latest version of Node.js installed (or, at least 13.2.0+). Then do one of the following, as [described in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field):

**Option 1**

In the nearest parent `package.json` file, add the top-level `"type"` field with a value of `"module"`. This will ensure that all `.js` and `.mjs` files are interpreted as ES modules. You can interpret individual files as [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) by using the `.cjs` extension.

```json
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

**Option 2**

Explicitly name files with the `.mjs` extension. All other files, such as `.js` will be interpreted as CommonJS, which is the default if `type` is not defined in `package.json`.

Comment: If I use this, then change the path to include the "js" for the required file, then change the format of the export statements in the required file, and then take all the "require" statements I changed from "import"—because now "require" is unknown—this will work, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: This is not really an option if the problem is under node_modules/ right? Any ideas how to fix in that case?

Comment: or use babel!
`
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
};
`

Comment: I'm at node 14.9.0, VSC, added `"type":"module"` solved `express`. But now **did you mean to import env.js** for `import env from './env'` Seems like I have to edit every file?

Comment: @Cocuba answer is spot on and should be the accepted answer because it actually transpiles.

Comment: Yes this works fine to my case that trying to import React module.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you're running ```.ts``` files. If you could add that simply using ```nodemon``` instead of ```node```, as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65058291/11664580 down below, it would hopefully save people the half a day I've spent messing around. Alternatively, installing ```ts-node``` seems to be a solution, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61947868/11664580

Comment: I had a hidden package.json in one of my source directories.  Had to do a `find . -name package.json` and my imports started working.

Comment: Adding `"type": "module"` isn't solving the error for me.

Comment: I like the additional note about the .cjs extension. Very useful.

Comment: my package.json file dont have a `{ "type":"module" }`
it have
`{
  "dependencies": {
     "chalk": "^4.1.2",
     "discord.js": "^14.6.0",
     "express": "^4.18.2",
     "pureimage": "^0.3.14"
   }
}`

Comment: But when I add `type: module`, if I use require, I'll get an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`

Comment: It breaks eslint. `[eslint] Cannot read config file`

Answer (score 201):

If anyone is running into this issue with [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript), the key to solving it for me was changing

```json
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
```

to

```json
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
```

In my `tsconfig.json`. I was under the impression "`esnext`" was the "best", but that was just a mistake.

Comment: If you're using `babel-node`, then you'll also need to use the `--extensions` option, e.g. `babel-node --extensions \".ts,.tsx\" src/index`

Comment: Yep, this did it where as trying "type" : "module" made it all of the sudden say "require is undefined".

Comment: Damn it saved me from lots of trouble. I did the same mistake coming under the impressino that `esnext` is the best

Comment: your answer works. could you explain why should we tweak like this? @Dr-Bracket Thank you

Comment: Simple and resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This has resolved the issue for me. Thanks. Could you please elaborate on why `esnext` was not the best option?

Comment: `esnext` is a false friend!

Comment: Could you elaborate more, lol.

Answer (score 119):

For those who were as confused as I was when reading the answers, in your package.json file, add
`"type": "module"`
in the upper level as show below:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": { ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: tx, but do you have an idea where I can find the package.json?? I am using netbeans. I also searched for package.json on my macbook but I see a lot of package.json files. Any tips?

Comment: Hi Alex, it's been a while since worked in Java project but I hope that this link can give you a clue on where to locate the package.json file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513559/netbeans-cant-run-package-json-on-maven-web-application

Comment: But when I add `type: module`, if I use require, I'll get an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`

Answer (score 84):

According to [the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_import_code_statements):

> import statements are permitted only in ES modules. For similar functionality in CommonJS, see import().

To make Node.js treat your file as an ES module, you need to (*[Enabling](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)*):

- add "type": "module" to package.json
- <strike>add "--experimental-modules" flag to the Node.js call</strike>

Comment: 2020 update: `--experimental-modules` is no longer required.

Comment: Not saying this answer is wrong, I've seen the same docs. But I don't see how the suggestion to use import() to access es6 module in CommonJS is useful. It's async and so can't be used to import anything at the file level. Which makes trying to access es6 modules from CommonJS painful to say the least. Considering that the main unit test frameworks Jasmine Jest etc don't handle this at all well it leaves me thinking that until there is better interop support the whole Node es6 situation seems half baked to me, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: add it where? Can we get a code example please.

Comment: adding it breaks my 'require's
`ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: @johnktejik [use `createRequire`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59443582/316310) to define a function in an ESM file that works like `require()` does in CommonJS files. _(The opposite way around—CJS in ESM—is simply `const foo = await import('./some-module.js')`)_

Comment: But when I add `type: module`, if I use require, I'll get an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784165/314114) for a code example using `import()`.

Answer (score 49):

I ran into the same issue and it's even worse: I needed both "import" and "require"

1. Some newer ES6 modules works only with *import*.
2. Some [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) works with *require*.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Turn your js file into .mjs as suggested in other answers
2. "require" is not defined with the ES6 module, so you can define it this way:

   ```
   import { createRequire } from 'module'
   const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
   ```

   Now 'require' can be used in the usual way.
3. Use *import* for ES6 modules and *require* for CommonJS.

Some useful links: [Node.js's own documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_require). [difference between import and require](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/). [Mozilla has some nice documentation about import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Reading the Node.js documentation, `import` will handle both `ES` and `CommonJS` modules; `require` only handles `CommonJS` modules. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue and the following has fixed it (using Node.js 12.13.1):

- Change `.js` files extension to `.mjs`
- Add `--experimental-modules` flag upon running your app.
- Optional: add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`

More information: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 18):

First we'll install `@babel/cli, @babel/core and @babel/preset-env`:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Then we'll create a *.babelrc* file for configuring [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)):

```
touch .babelrc
```

This will host any options we might want to configure Babel with:

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

With recent changes to Babel, you will need to transpile your **ES6** before Node.js can run it.

So, we'll add our first script, build, in file *package.json*.

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel index.js -d dist"
}
```

Then we'll add our start script in file *package.json*.

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel index.js -d dist", // replace index.js with your filename
  "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js"
}
```

Now let's start our server.

```
npm start
```

Comment: does this work with nodemon hot reloading in development?

Answer (score 16):

I tried with all the methods, but nothing worked.

I got one reference from GitHub.

To use TypeScript imports with Node.js, I installed the below packages.

1. `npm i typescript --save-dev`
2. `npm i ts-node --save-dev`

**Won't require type: module in package.json**

For example,

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "knex": "^0.16.3",
    "pg": "^7.9.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. As an alternative, simply running the package.json script using ```nodemon``` instead of ```node``` works too. Saves the need for installing another package (assuming you're already running nodemon). credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65058291/11664580

Comment: They should go to devDependencies instead.

Answer (score 10):

Step 1

```
yarn add esm
```

or

```
npm i esm --save
```

Step 2

package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node -r esm src/index.js",
}
```

Step 3

```
nodemon --exec npm start
```

Comment: +1 `esm` seems to be the easiest solution when you cannot add `"type": "module"` to the `package.json` file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `esm` solves the issue. Thank you.

For anyone trying to import express or any other module into your Express application instead of doing a `require`, this is ideal.

Answer (score 10):

Node.js v14.16.0:

For those who've tried .mjs and got:

```
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex$ node just_js.mjs
file:///mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/just_js.mjs:3
import fetch from "node-fetch";
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and who've tried `import fetch from "node-fetch";`
and who've tried `const fetch = require('node-fetch');`

```
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex$ node just_js.js
(node:4899) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/just_js.js:3
import fetch from "node-fetch";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and who've tried `"type": "module"` to package.json, yet continue seeing the error,

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "to get fetch working",
  "main": "just_js.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I was able to switch to [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) without a problem.

`import axios from 'axios';` <-- put at top of file.
Example:

```
axios.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml').then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data);
});
```

Comment: this worked for me. Wtf is up with node-fetch?

Comment: I usually don't mind "solving the problem" a different way but using a different library that doesn't have the same module semantics seems like last-resort and didn't really solve or understand the original problem which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) JavaScript imports:

1. install `cross-env`
2. in `package.json` change `"test": "jest"` to `"test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"`
3. more in `package.json`, add these:

```json
    ...,
    "jest": {
        "transform": {}
    },
    "type": "module"
```

Explanation:

*cross-env* allows to change environment variables without changing the npm command. Next, in file *package.json* you change your npm command to enable experimental ES6 support for [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)), and configure Jest to do it.

Answer (score 9):

I found the 2020 update to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export/31367852#31367852) helpful to answering this question as well as telling you *why* it does this:

Here's an excerpt:

> Since Node.js v12 (April 2019), support for ES modules is enabled by default, and since Node.js v15 (October 2020) it's stable (see here). Files, including Node.js modules, must either end in .mjs or the nearest package.json file must contain "type": "module". The Node.js documentation has a ton more information, also about interoperability between CommonJS and ES modules.

Comment: I found this answer the most clear explanation to OP. Just that, say I'm writing an app, not a module, does _"Cannot use import statement outside a module"_ means that I cannot use the `import` statement to import anything, since I'm outside a module, right? This is still confusing. For _"Files including node modules must either end in .mjs or the nearest package.json file must contain "type": "module"."_, I'm writing an app, not a module, why I need to name my app with mjs or set my package to module?

Comment: @xpt Hey. So, you can't compare an app and a module. I think you maybe be thinking of it in terms of node modules which seems like a program within your program. This isn't really what a module is. Let me clarify what a module is and I think that'll solve your confusion:

Comment: @xpt Think of it this way, you're writing an app and working on a file named main-file.js. You want to import a function from another file called some-other-file.js. some-other-file.js is quite large and you don't need the entire file. You just want a function from the file. Now if some-other-file.js and main-file.js were modules (.mjs), you could 'import' the function you so desire e.g. import someFunction from './some-other-file'. To sum it up, a module is a js file that can be separated by its functions so it can export particular functions opposed to the whole file. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation David. So I understand some-other-file.js is module, which can export particular functions opposed to the whole file. However, is main-file.js a module too? No, it's only my main of my app. Would the "Cannot use import statement outside a module" rule apply to main-file.js (since it is not a module)?

Comment: Anyway, I think I'd better ask a new question instead -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240736/

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 7):

I'm new to Node.js, and I got the same issue for the AWS Lambda function (using Node.js) while fixing it.

I found some of the differences between [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) and [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) JavaScript:

***ES6:***

- Add "type":"module" in the *package.json* file
- Use "import" to use from lib.

  **Example**: import jwt_decode from jwt-decode
- Lambda handler method code should be define like this

  "exports.handler = async (event) => { }"

***CommonJS:***

- Don't add "type":"module" in the *package.json* file
- Use "require" to use from lib.

  **Example**: const jwt_decode = require("jwt-decode");
- The lambda handler method code should be defines like this:

  "export const handler = async (event) => { }"

Answer (score 6):

In my case. I think the problem is in the standard `node` executable. `node target.ts`

I replaced it with [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and surprisingly it worked!

The way using the standard executable (runner):

```
node target.ts
```

The way using the nodemon executable (runner):

```
nodemon target.ts
```

Do not forget to install nodemon with `npm install nodemon` ;P

*Note*: this works amazing for development. But, for runtime, you may execute `node` with the compiled *.js* file!

The problem is that `node` does not accept TypeScript files.
Instead, `ts-node` might be the perfect replacement.

Comment: Perhaps nodemon executes files as modules, so intrinsically error disappears

Answer (score 6):

To use import, do one of the following.

1. Rename the **.js** file to **.mjs**
2. In **package.json** file, add **{type:module}**

Comment: this works without adding `{type:module}` in **package.json**

Comment: Lol, since when the Nodejs files must be named ".mjs" instead of ".js". Weird, but it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This error also comes when you run the command

```
node filename.ts
```

and not

```
node filename.js
```

Simply put, with the `node` command we will have to run the JavaScript file (*filename.js*) and not the TypeScript file unless we are using a package like *ts-node*.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error in my **NX workspace** after upgrading manually. The following change in each `jest.config.js` fixed it:

```
transform: {
  '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
},
```

to

```
transform: {
  '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
},
```

Comment: That works for me. Thks. But now i'm giving this error `The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), I have a simple solution for that!

Remember this is for Node.js example: like an [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) server!

If you are going to use [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) or another framework, look in the Babel documentation!

**First**, install (do not install unnecessary things that will only trash your project!)

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/node
```

#### Just 2

Then configure your Babel file in your repository!

[image: Example for Express.js server Node.js and Babel]

File name:

```
babel.config.json
```

---

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

---

---

If you don't want to use the Babel file, use:

Run in your console, and script.js is your entry point!

```
npx babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env -- script.js
```

[image: Example Babel without a file]

The full information is on *[@babel/node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node)*.

Comment: What is *"WAO"*?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vite/info) - React application with the Speedy Web Compiler ([SWC](https://swc.rs/)) and you tried to import the various methods of the [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(framework)) testing library
(`{import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";`), all your tests will run individually and outside the module. Hence you might get the error as:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Since you are using SWC, the [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) configuration won't help. So it could be resolved by just giving a simple development dependency:

`npm install --save-dev @types/jest`

Later remove the *import* statement, use methods (describe, test, expect, afterAll, afterEach, beforeAll, beforeEach, fail, fdescribe, fit, it, jasmine, jest, pending, spyOn, xdescribe, xit, xtest) directly since there are treated as globals. Install the link and other documentation here! [@types/jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest)

Test your sum.test.js by `npm run test`, supposing you have`"test": "jest"` in scripts commands and jest in dev dependency:

```js
const sum = (val1, val2) => {
  return val1 + val2;
};

describe("sum module", () => {
  test("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `--presets '@babel/preset-env'`.

For example,

```
babel-node --trace-deprecation --presets '@babel/preset-env' ./yourscript.js
```

*Or*

in `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your import work and avoid other issues, like modules not working in Node.js, just note that:

With ES6 modules you can not yet import directories. Your import should look like this:

```js
import fs from './../node_modules/file-system/file-system.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I was running a migration.

It's an [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009) vs. [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) issue.

Here is how I solved it:

I run

```
npm install @babel/register
```

and add

```
require("@babel/register")
```

at the top of my *.sequelizerc* file my.

And go ahead to run my sequelize migrate.
This is applicable to other things, apart from sequelize.

[Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) does the [transpiling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpile#Verb).

Comment: What do you mean by *".sequelizerc file my"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65089232/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

For people coming to this question due to this error in [Netlify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlify) functions even after adding `"type": "module"` in the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file, update your *netlify.toml* file to use 'esbuild'. Since esbuild supports [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), it would work.

```
[functions]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
```

Reference: *[Get started with functions](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/build-with-javascript/#automated-dependency-bundling)*

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is confusing. I use Node.js to perform some local task in my computer.

Let's suppose my old script was **test.js**. **Within it**, if I want to use

```
import something from "./mylocalECMAmodule";
```

it will throw an error like this:

```
(node:16012) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
...
```

This is *not* a module error, but a Node.js error. Forbid loading anything outside a 'module'.

To fix this, just rename your old script **test.js** into **test.mjs**.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to include babel-node path while running nodemon as follows:

```
nodemon node_modules/.bin/babel-node index.js
```

You can add in your *package.json* script as:

```
debug: nodemon node_modules/.bin/babel-node index.js
```

*Note*: My entry file is **index.js**. Replace it with **your entry file** (many have *app.js/server.js*).

Answer (score 0):

1. I had the same problem when I started to use Babel... But later, I
   had a solution... I haven't had the problem any more so far...
   Currently, Node.js v12.14.1, "@babel/node": "^7.8.4",  I use babel-node and nodemon to execute (Node.js is fine as well..)
2. **package.json:**  "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js "debug": "babel-node debug server.js"!! Note: *server.js* is my entry
   file, and you can use yours.
3. **launch.json**. When you debug, you also need to configure your *launch.json* file "runtimeExecutable":
   "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node"!! Note: plus
   runtimeExecutable into the configuration.
4. Of course, with babel-node, you also normally need and edit another file, such as the *babel.config.js/.babelrc* file

Answer (score 0):

In case you're running nodemon for the Node.js version 12, use this command.

**server.js** is the "main" inside `package.json` file, replace it with the relevant file inside your *package.json* file:

```
nodemon --experimental-modules server.js
```

Comment: this flag seems to have been removed from latest versions

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the issue. The fix which worked for me was to add this to file *babel.config.json* in the plugins section:

```json
["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", {
    "allowTopLevelThis": true,
    "loose": true,
    "lazy": true
  }],
```

I had some imported module with /**/** and the error "cannot use import outside a module".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.js, you should refer to [this document](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setup-babel-in-nodejs/). Just set up [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) in your Node.js application. It will work, and it worked for me.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Comment: this did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong MIME-Type for JavaScript Module Files

**The common source of the problem is the MIME-type for "Module" type JavaScript files is not recognized as a "module" type by the server, the client, or the ECMAScript engine that process or deliver these files.**

The problem is the developers of Module JavaScript files incorrectly associated Modules with a new ".mjs" (.js) extension, but then assigned it a MIME-type server type of "text/javascript". This means both .js and .mjs types are the same. In fact the new type for .js JavaScript files has also changed to "application/javascript", further confusing the issue. So Module JavaScript files are not being recognized by any of these systems, regardless of Node.js or Babel file processing systems in development.

The main problem is this new "module" subtype of JavaScript is yet known to most servers or clients (modern HTML5 browsers). In other words, they have no way to know what a ***Module file type*** truly is apart from a JavaScript type!

So, you get the response you posted, where the JavaScript engine is saying it needs to know if the file is a Module type of JavaScript file.

The only solution, for server or client, is to **`change your server or browser to deliver a new Mime-type that trigger ES6 support of Module files`**, which have an `.mjs` extension. Right now, the only way to do that is to either create a `HTTP content-type` on the server of "`module`" for any file with a `.mjs` extension and change your file extension on module JavaScript files to ".mjs", or have an HTML script tag with `type="module"` added to any external `<script>` element you use that downloads your external `.js` JavaScript module file.

Once you fool the browser or JavaScript engines into accepting the new Module file type, they will start doing their scripting circus tricks in the JS engines or Node.js systems you use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the swc command to [transpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler), and the problem was the *.wscrc* file missing. Due to the lack of this file, it was not being transpiled and that is why there is an error.

My solution:

- Transpile command on package.json
  `"dist": "swc src -d dist --source-maps --copy-files",`
- .wscrc config file:

```
{
    "jsc": {
      "parser": {
        "syntax": "typescript",
        "tsx": false,
        "dynamicImport": true,
        "decorators": true
      },
      "transform": {
        "legacyDecorator": true,
        "decoratorMetadata": true
      },
      "target": "es2020",
      "externalHelpers": false,
      "keepClassNames": true,
      "loose": false,
      "minify": {
        "compress": false,
        "mangle": false
      },
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "paths": {
        "@/*": ["*"]
      }
    },
    "module": {
      "type": "commonjs"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem in a fledgling Express API project.

The offending server code in `src/server/server.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
import {initialDonationItems, initialExpenditureItems} from "./DemoData";

const server = express();

server.get('/api/expenditures', (req, res) => {
  res.type('json');
  res.send(initialExpenditureItems);
});

server.get('/api/donations', (req, res) => {
  res.type('json');
  res.send(initialDonationItems);
});

server.listen(4242, () => console.log('Server is running...'));
```

Here were my dependencies:

```json
{
  "name": "contributor-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Node backend to provide storage services",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore dist/",
    "test": "jest tests"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

And here was the runner that threw the error:

```
nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore dist
```

This was frustrating, as I had a similar Express project that worked fine.

The solution was firstly to add this dependency:

```
npm install @babel/preset-env
```

And then to wire it in using a `babel.config.js` in the project root:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
};
```

I don't fully grok why this works, but I copied it from [an authoritative source](https://jscomplete.com/learn/1rd-reactful), so I am happy to stick with it.

Comment: Yeah, my issue was that the code had a *bunch* of presets and I could never quite hit the balance right of things I wanted vs. things I didn't want/that broke stuff.

Comment: I've been pushing through confusing JS crashes all day @user3810626 - I suspect my problem is that I'm quite new to the language and the ecosystem, and I need to put some learning aside for now to get stuff working. Getting there... `:-)`

Comment: Good luck! It's a jungle out there! (I mean, literally, the JS ecosystem is a jungle...)

Comment: @user3810626 nodejs devs dont know how things work anymore. they just keep trying [so] solutions until something sticks

Comment: This seems to be truer in some communities than others.

Answer (score -1):

When I used sequelize migrations with `npx sequelize db:migrate`, I got this error, so my solution for this was adding the line `require('@babel/register');` into the *.sequelizerc* file as the following image shows:

[image]

Be aware you must install [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) and Babel [register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register/).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71944570/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.