# Get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when attempting to import a class in Jasmine spec file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jasmine, es6-modules

As an exercise I decided to create a little vanilla JavaScript game using ES6 syntax that runs in the browser. The program works fine.

I'd like to test it using Jasmine. However, whenever I try to perform an import e.g.

```
import Deck from "../Deck.js";
```

Deck.js starts:

```
export default class Deck {
```

I get error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Things I've done:

- Installed node v13.0.1 - I thought this version of node allowed es6 modules.
- Installed jasmine and initialized `node ./node_module/jasmine/bin/jasmine init`
- Run `node ./node_module/jasmine/bin/jasmine` - works fine without imports
- Run `node --experimental-modules ./node_module/jasmine/bin/jasmine` - doesn't work with imports
- Tried require instead of import: `const Deck = require('../Deck.js');` - `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

How do I get jasmine to work with imports? At the moment I cannot include any files to test !

I'm sure I've gone about this the wrong way, but i just want some cmd line tests.

Comment: `const Deck = require('../Deck');`

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: What directory location is your jasmine file in? Is your jasmine spec file in the module? Have you added a specRunner.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the offical guide from Babel at https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

Then choose one of the options from this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/673351

Personally, I have renamed my spec files to have the `mjs` extension becaue I would like ot use the LTS (currently 12) version of node.