# Deploy Node application in Heroku with ES6 modules?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Node.js ES6 modules-based application to Heroku, it works fine locally with `npm start` and also when I run `heroku local web` but unfortunately in the deployment it throws the error attached in the screenshot.

[image]

This is how my `package.json` looks like.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-modules index.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have also tried by upgrading Node to 13.2.0 as suggested in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/5763627, but nothing changes with Heroku.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: its a deployment issue could you please let me know how can I give minimal reproducible example here?  @jonrsharpe.

Comment: Would need to see your `config.js` file. That is where the error is being raised. Perhaps it's a build item and the build on your local machine is different from the config file that is built by heroku on your server

Comment: @elightI fixed it it was something with Heroku deployment cache. although thanks :)