# How to use the file on the backend and frontend at the same time?

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs server.
I have a file with a class in which the functionality is written.
The functionality of this class is the same for the backend and for the frontend.
I do not want to create two files with the same functionality.

A file with a class has dependencies - other classes in other files.

How to connect files on the backend and frontend?
What should the classes look like for this?

nodejs back-end app.js:

```js
let player = new Player();

player.goTo(10,20);
```

front-end index.js:

```js
let player = new Player();

player.goTo(10,20);
```

It's files need include to frontend and backend:

Player.js:

```js
Class Player
{
  goTo(x,y){
   Path.pathFinding()
  }
}
```

Path.js:

```js
Class Path
{
  pathFinding(){
   //doing something
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply `import`/`require` it from the right path. May be keep a shared folder between the `server` and `client` directories and import it. That should do.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to put this `.js` file in the folder from where you are hosting static files to serve to the frontend. Whether this be `/public` or `/views` or whatever name you called this folder. And in the file next to your class you type in the keyword `export`: `export class {...}`. I'm sure you have already done this but no assumptions. Then in your server file simply import it into your server file like this:

```
import myClass from "/public/js/myjsfile.js";
```

Example:

`public/js/dog.js`:

```
export class dog {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

`server.js`:

```
import dog from "/public/js/dog.js";
```

The dependencies that are used in `dog.js` or the client side file will come along with it when you import the file on the backend.

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to import this on the client side.

Comment: It works the exact same way on the client side, as long as you are hosting those files with express or http or some http library.

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/9525737, but a new error appeared

Comment: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /app/app.mjs

Comment: Where are you getting this error, the backend or the frontend?