# Node.js: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I am getting this error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when trying to import from another javascript file. This is the first time I'm trying something like this. The main file is `main.js` and the module file is `mod.js`.

main.js:

```
import * as myModule from "mod";
myModule.func();
```

mod.js:

```
export function func(){
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Which version of nodejs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: @gautam1168 v12.16.2

Answer (score 177, accepted):

In order to use the import syntax (ESModules), you need to add the following to your package.json at the top level:

```
{
    // ...
    "type": "module",
}
```

If you are using a version of Node earlier than 13, you additionally need to use the `--experimental-modules` flag when you run the program:

```
node --experimental-modules program.js
```

Comment: **Note - Add a comma at the end of codpiece provided**

Comment: not working for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71757466/470749 was helpful.

Comment: Actually, for NodeJS to interpret a script as a module, you only need to have a `package.json` file with just `{ "type": "module" }` into the closest ancestor directory, including the same directory as your script.

Comment: @EklavyaChandra are you sure you meant codpiece? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codpiece

Comment: @mikemaccana I think I mean to say code, autocorrect maybe ☕

Answer (score 35):

Use commonjs syntax instead of es module syntax:

```
module.exports.func = function (){
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

and

```
const myMod = require("./mod")
myMod.func()
```

Otherwise, if you want to use es modules you have to do as the answer by Achraf Ghellach suggests

Comment: Assuming `./mod` is a file named `mod.js`  containing part 1 of your answer, I still get `ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Comment: Assuming you have nodejs 16 or higher it should work. Are you maybe using the keyword `module` during require as a variable?
Check this screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/D41OnBGMT81z.png

Comment: unfortunately I'm using pretty old version... 12 :(

Comment: I don't know if this will help on that version, but you may try after adding the extension:
`var mymod = require("./mod.js")`. This require style is pretty old so I would have expected it to work on node 12 as well.

Answer (score 10):

For **browser(front end)**:
add type = "module" inside your **script** tag i.e

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

For **nodejs**:
add `"type": "module"`, in your **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "type": "module",
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered this problem. This solution is similar to the top rated answer but with some ways I found worked for me.

In the same directory as your modules **create** a package.json file and add `"type":"module"`. Then use import `{func} from "./myscript.js";`. The import style works when run using node.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, note by default(if the "type" is omitted) the "type" is "commonjs". So, you have explicitly specify the type when it's "module". You cannot use an import statement outside a module.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the browser (instead of a Node environment), make sure you specify the `type="module"` attribute in your `script` tag. If you want to use Babel, then it must be `type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" data-type="module"`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue but in another module (python-shell).
I replaced the code as follows:

```
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell'; (original code)
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
```

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a js script by `node --experimental-modules` without changing `package.json` as below:

```
node --experimental-modules ./path/to/your/js/script.mjs
```

Note that you need change your script ext to `.mjs`, otherwise a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error will occur.

Comment: As of Node 13 there is no need to use `--experimental-modules` flag, see https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue with Node 18 with a single file `src/index.js` that uses `import` statements, here's the error message I got:

```
(node:13859) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node-18 --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[...redacted...]src/index.js:5
import { createServer } from 'node:http'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

The only things I had to do to resolve this was rename my `src/index.js` to `src/index.mjs` and start it with the command `node src/index.mjs` (`node src` finds index.js but not `index.mjs`). Happy day:

```
$ node src/index.mjs 
Server is running on http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to run mocha tests with typescript. This isn't directly related to the answer but may help some.

[This article](https://journal.artfuldev.com/unit-testing-node-applications-with-typescript-using-mocha-and-chai-384ef05f32b2) is quite interesting. He's using a trick involving `cross-env`, that allows him to run tests as commonjs module type. That worked for me.

```json
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{ \"module\": \"commonjs\" }' mocha -r ts-node/register -r src/**/*.spec.ts"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had my typescript project and I wanted to run a ts file, while running `node file.ts`  Turns out I was using the wrong command to run the file.

Command to use:
`npx tsc file.ts`

Followed by:
`node file.js`

Running the first command will compile the ts and generate a new file with same name but ts extension.