# Typescript and Node.js error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, eslint, google-cloud-run

After running rpm run start, an error gets printed: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
NOTE: I'm using this with GCP Cloud Run.

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "auth-api-public",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.ts",
    "lint": "eslint src/**.ts",
    "fix": "eslint --fix *.ts"
  },
  "author": "Jacob Miller",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^3.9.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.0",
    "stytch": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "5.1.0"
  }
}
```

Then I have a folder named src with the file containing the import statements in index.ts (see screenshot with file structure).
[image: File Structure]

This is the import statement code:

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as stytch from "stytch";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

This is the tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}

    // {
    //   "compilerOptions": {
    //     "outDir": "./built",
    //     "allowJs": true,
    //     "target": "es6",
    //     "noImplicitReturns": true,
    //     "noUnusedLocals": true,
    //    "moduleResolution": "node",
    //     "sourceMap": true,
    //     "strict": false,
    //   },
    //   "include": ["src"],
    //   "compileOnSave": true,
    // }
```

Then the error message after running npm run start screenshot:
[image: Error]

Comment: it's hard to say, but at least I see you missed ts-node in your devdep, so do `npm i ts-node -D`

Comment: also take a look at nestjs, which is a framework with power of typescript, and we developed our app by nestjs and deploy to cloud run

Comment: Ok, I’ve been looking into Nest last night and morning but have one question, with cloud run as well as cloud functions, will any configuration be required? Heres what I mean:   I run the command to create nest project. I have the nest cats template. Then I want to deploy to cloud run or functions. What do I need to configure so the GCP works with nest?

Comment: https://whatdafox.com/deploy-nest-js-on-google-cloud-run/

Comment: @JacobMiller posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Comment: Yes everyone, thank you for your help. I had a few issues with multiple ways to fix. I changed the syntax to match some settings in the tsconfig.json and I also reinstalled and reconfigured tsc and ts-node.

Comment: @JacobMiller You may want to post your solution as answer to help the community as well which has similar or related concerns and or issues.

Comment: @JacobMiller can you share your solution and post it as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

I hope Typescript is globally installed (`npm i -g typescript`).  Apart from installing JavaScript npm, you should install Typescript version as well.  Below is an example how to do that,
`npm install express @types/express` 
Do this for all npm modules for which Typescript version Exists. Share configuration of tsconfig.json here.  Make sure you are using commonjs there.

Check if below configuration works for you.

````
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}                                                                                                                 ```
````

Comment: Ok, the comments are what I originally had. I added the tsconfig to the question. No, this configuration did not work.

Comment: Also I installed the types packages and uninstalled the originals but that did not help.

Answer (score -1):

You can go through Stackoverflow Questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488898/node-js-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) where a similar error has been faced by the OP.
You can also refer to the [link1](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922) and [link2](https://xperimentalhamid.com/how-do-i/fix-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module/) where a similar issue has been raised and discussed regarding the syntax error : cannot use import statement outside the module.

make sure you are working on the latest version for Nodejs and if the version is before 13 then you also have to  add a flag in the package.json file along with above changes.

Syntax :

```
         node --experimental-modules program.js
```

Comment: You can clearly see in the question that they used {"type"; "module"}

Comment: @SamDean You were right.. now updated.