# Cypress: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

A team member uses cypress alone without a package.json, IDE setup or framework and receives the following error message:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

**The first part of the e2e test looks like this:**

```
describe('Dummy', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseURL'));
    cy.contains('Log in').click();
    cy.get('input[name="username"]').type('test user').should('have.value', 'test user');
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type('test password').should('have.value', 'test password');
  });
});
```

The tests are partially running and the first two commands (visit & contains) work in the example provided.

But when it comes to the line in which a username and password must be entered, the test failed with the error message mentioned above.

I think he is trying to execute it as an ES2015 module, but node.js only understands CommonJS. There are possibilities to fix it in the package.json, but since it doesn’t use a package.json I don't know what to do.

Is there another workaround for this?

Answer (score -2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488998/6295318). These are typical things you would define in your (test) code's `package.json` and/or `tsconfig.json` (when using TypeScript). Doing this beforehand prevents all sorts of "(doesn't) work(s) on my machine" issues like the the one you just described.