# Unknown file extension ".ts" error appears when trying to run a ts-node script

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to run a script created in a regular folder with two .ts files. One with the script and one with helper functions to run it. I'm also importing more things such as axios or form-data.

The thing is that when I try to run the script with ts-node: *node script.ts*, the following error appears:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "showdown": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

And my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My imports in the script.ts file are:

```
import { datoManagementPrimaryEnvironment } from "./content.management";
import {
  createContent,
  uploadToCloudfare,
  getEntryFromDatoWithTheId,
  getFilters,
} from "./helpers";
```

and in helpers.ts:

```
import { datoManagementPrimaryEnvironment } from "./content.management";
import axios from "axios";
import FormData from "form-data";
var showdown = require("showdown");
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Please give a [mre] - _how_ are you importing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for that, I've just edited and added the imports to the question. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: And are you actually running it _with_ ts-node?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm running in the terminal (under the folder I'm working in): node script.ts

Comment: That's **not** using TS-node, just regular node, no?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm willing to use ts-node. But when I run 'npx ts-node reptile.ts' it appears the same error.

Answer (score 25):

Use the `--esm` switch for ts-node.

Eg

```
ts-node --esm index.ts
```

This requires you to have the module to set to one of the newer ones (like `nodenext` or `node16`) and moduleResolution also set to a newer method, in your tsconfig.

Comment: @mikemaccana the same as module values (eg, nodenext, node16)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve it. But it doesn't explain why ts-node emits such a spectacularly unhelpful and misleading error when omitting this parameter :-(

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me. Thanks to @Slava for pointing me in the right direction.

Linking the documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/cd7a54035eff5dc1c7c2eff096b23b6b#using-with-ts-node).

> The easiest method is to add esm: true to your TypeScript config file:
>
> ```
> {   
>   "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",  
>   "extends": "@tsconfig/node-lts-strictest-esm/tsconfig.json",  
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     // …   
>   },   
>   "include": [
>     // …   
>   ],   
>   "ts-node": {
>     "esm": true, // «———— enabling ESM for ts-node   
>   }, 
> }
> ```

The only thing I was missing was adding `"esm": true,` because I already have ts-config setup for esm. But if you have nothing, it's probably helpful to add the `"$schema"` and `"extends"`.

I also needed to add `"type": "module"` in the package.json file.

Answer (score 9):

Remove `"type": "module"` from your package.json

And change your `tsconfig.json` to:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I already tried that. This error appears then: 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Comment: `"moduleResolution":"node"` was missing too in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Still appears the same error: 'Unknown file extension ".ts"'

Comment: You changed package.json and tsconfig.json ? hum it's working fine on my computer

Comment: When I change those, this previous error appears: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Comment: Hi Thomas, I finally solved this. But now when I run the script with 'ts-node script.ts', nothing happens, and I'm logging the errors in the console, but they don't appear... the script should have something? because mine consists in an 
export default async (req, res) => {
...my script...
}

Comment: Great ! How did you solve it ? Can you share your `script.ts` file pls ?

Comment: Yeah how did you resolve it, friend? ^ I also have this issue - "Hi, thanks for the answer, but I already tried that. This error appears then: 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module' – 
"

Comment: What if I want to use ESM?

Comment: These days it's possible to pass `--esm` to ts-node to make it understand esm, as  outlined in @victor-p 's answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Here's how you use TypeScript with native ESM

1. Update your `package.json` to have:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  // …
}
```

2. Install the `@tsconfig/node-lts-strictest-esm` dependency:

```bash
npm i -D @tsconfig/node-lts-strictest-esm
```

3. Update your `tsconfig.json` to have:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node-lts-strictest-esm/tsconfig.json",
  // …
}
```

5. Use imports with `.js` extension in your TS source files, e.g.:

```
import { Foo } from './common/foo.js';
```

6. Then use the `ts-node-esm file.ts` command instead of `ts-node file.ts`.

This should do the trick.

---

Also, look at the [detailed guide](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/cd7a54035eff5dc1c7c2eff096b23b6b).

Answer (score 0):

This command solves my life:

```bash
ts-node --compiler-options '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' /path/to/file.ts
```

Comment: That is for CommonJS and will not work with ESM. You are basically just telling ts-node that it is CommonJS, you are not changing its behavior.

Answer (score -9):

When you want to use ts-node you should try running the file with `ts-node scripts.ts` instead of `node scripts.ts`.

You can also refer to the usage examples on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)