# Jest encountered an unexpected token For Typescrip

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jestjs, ts-jest

The path to my development directory is here.

```
.
├── README.md
└── business
    ├── jest.config.ts
    ├── nodeLayer
    │   └── db
    │       ├── README.md
    │       ├── dist
    │       │   └── db
    │       │       ├── index.js
    │       │       └── index.js.map
    │       │  
    │       ├── package-lock.json
    │       ├── package.json
    │       ├── src
    │            └── index.ts
    │       
    └── hoge1
        └── src
            ├── README.md
            ├── app
            │   └── app.ts
            ├── jest.config.ts
            ├── package-lock.json
            ├── package.json
            └── tests
                └── unit
                    └── get.test.ts
```

The following error occurs when I run the test with Jest.

```
➤ npm run test

> sync_app_info_to_aam_db@1.0.0 test
> npm run unit


> sync_app_info_to_aam_db@1.0.0 unit
> NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest --config jest.config.ts

 FAIL  tests/unit/get.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /xxxxxxxx/business/nodeLayer/db/dist/db/index.js:2
    import { createPool } from 'mysql2/promise';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       5 | import { ConnectionArguments, Db, SelectArguments } from '/opt/nodejs/dist/db';
       6 |
    >  7 | export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
         |              ^
       8 |     const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
       9 |         region: 'ap-northeast-1',
      10 |     });

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/app.ts:7:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/get.test.ts:4:15)
```

The import of app.ts is here.
Since we are importing the Lambda Layer, the @ts-ignore is commented out because it will be detected as any type.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
import { ConnectionArguments, Db, SelectArguments } from '/opt/nodejs/dist/db';
```

Here are the settings in the jest.config.ts file.

```
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/*.test.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['cf/.aws-sam/build'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^/opt/nodejs/dist/db$': '<rootDir>/nodeLayer/db/dist/db',
    },
};
```

As I looked into it, I saw that commonjs can't handle imports, so I had to change to ECM.

Please provide a solution to the problem here.

If you need any other information, just let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488898/node-js-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: This question was not helpful.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

The solution was to change some of the contents of jest.config.ts.
Now it recognizes the esm format by default.

```
preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',.
```

This problem is solved, but we have another problem, which we will create a separate question for.