# Typescript Jest ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to use jest to start unit testing and I came across this error like this one.

```
> npm run unit


> hoge@1.0.0 unit
> NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest --config jest.config.ts

 FAIL  tests/unit/get.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: exports is not defined

      1 | import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
    > 2 | import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
        |                       ^
      3 | import { lambdaHandler } from '../../app/app';
      4 |
      5 | describe('Unit test for syncAppInfoToAamDb', () => {

      at tests/unit/get.test.ts:2:23
```

Here is my code.

```
import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { lambdaHandler } from '../../app/app';

describe('Unit test for test', () => {
    it('test', async () => {
        ....
        
        const res = lambdaHandler(event, context);
        expect(res).toEqual('test');
    });
});
```

Earlier I asked here about `Jest encountered an unexpected token` and modified jest.config.ts

[Jest encountered an unexpected token For Typescrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943978/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token-for-typescrip)

```
// jest.config.ts

export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/*.test.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['cf/.aws-sam/build'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^/opt/nodejs/dist/db(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../../nodeLayer/db/dist/db$1',
    },
};
```

Since jest said that it supports the commonjs format by default, we decided to add `preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm'`.

What is the cause of this problem?
Please tell me if there is a problem with another file.
I will include the descriptions of the other files.

Comment: `npm install aws-lambda`?

Comment: No, I have already installed aws-lambda.The same error occurs when the import statement is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support) doc:

1. if you are using a custom transform you should remove the preset config
2. **transform** config should include the `useESM` option
3. **moduleNameMapper** config is missing this regex: `'^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1'`
4. **extensionsToTreatAsEsm** config is missing

this is my **jest.config.ts**:

```js
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from "ts-jest";

const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1",
  },
};

export default config;
```