# Unable to import the module in node

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to import the logger.js in app.js but facing an error again and again.
Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside the module.

### logger.js

```
    var url='http://mylogger.io/log';
function log(message){

    //send an http request;
    console.log(message);
}
module.export.log=log;
```

### app.js

```
import logger from './logger';
```

I am using node 12.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to import from logger.js change:
**app.js**

```
var newlog = require('./logger.js');
```

For a more detailed clarification, you can check [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESM (ECMAScript Module) syntax like `import logger from './logger';` you must specify ESM exports.

**NOTE**: if you are using v12, you must be using Node.js v12.17.0 or above ([changelog reference](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V12.md#2020-05-26-version-12170-erbium-lts-targos)) or using the `--experimental-modules` flag.

In addition you must specify `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` as [@Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80911/evert) mentioned

So:

**logger.js**

```
var url='http://mylogger.io/log';

// or export function log(message) {
function log(message){

    //send an http request;
    console.log(message);
}

export default log;
```

**app.js**

```
import logger from './logger';
```

**package.json**

Specify `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "<project>",
  "version": "<version>",
  "description": "<description>",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  ......
}
```

Reference [Node.js ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: @iSkore.Thank you for your response.

Comment: Instead of using this syntax I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Did you modify your `package.json` with the key-value `"type": "module"`?

Comment: no i didn't modify,Is it necessary to modify in every JSON file.

Comment: You must add that key-value pair to your `package.json` in your root module. I edited my answer to show an example `package.json`