# Nodejs - import stuff from mjs file into js file OR how to use require in mjs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JS and Node. From what I been reading it seems like [ES6 import is not supported in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/45854500#45854500) so I am forced to use [experiment mode (renaming my file to mjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/50641589#50641589)

This works for the most part unless the mjs file needs to use `require`. My current solution is to break out the chunk of code that depends on require to a seperate .js file and import that js file

foo.mjs

```
import readFileSync from './util.js'
... 
//orignally just do require('fs') and do fs.readFileSync()
const configFile = readFileSync(configFilePath);
```

util.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function readFileSync(filePath) {
  console.log(__dirname)
  console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, filePath))
  return fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, filePath), 'utf8');
}

module.exports = readFileSync
```

Is there a way I can avoid doing this? My app.js has lots of `require` and I don't want to break out all those parts into separate js files.

I tried changing require to import

```
// const express = require('express');
import * as express from 'express';
```

but when run  `node  --experimental-modules app.mjs`

I get an error

```
TypeError: express is not a function
```

I think I need to either

- find a way to use `require` in mjs
- or find a way to import stuff in mjs into a js file

Answer (score 17):

You have three decent options:

- Use Babel or TypeScript to get interoperability between the two types of modules
- Write a little wrapper to redefine `require` in ESM code
- Use `import()` (dynamic import) in your CJS to import ESM code

The wrapper to use `require` in ESM code:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)
const cjsFile = require('./test') // test is regular .js file using module.exports
```

Dynamic imports:

```
// foo.mjs:
export const foo = () => true
// index.js:
import('./foo.mjs').then(x => console.log(x.foo()))
```

Large projects with mixed module types frequently use Babel and/or TypeScript, both of which handle the mixed types just fine. Babel would be simpler to learn and get set up. But if you don't have a ton of code to deal with, the `createRequire` method works just fine.

As for the issue with Express, it failed because the default export is what you want: `import express from 'express'`, not `import * as express...`.

Comment: I see. I tried your code above and see that
 `SyntaxError: The requested module 'module' does not provide an export named 'createRequire'`

Comment: What version of Node are you on? That was added in v12.2.0 (Node 14 is currently the Active LTS version).

Comment: I am on v10.23.1

Comment: I'm not sure what you can do in that case, then. Node 10 has only seen security patches for the last year and will be EOL in three months from now... it's probably time to update :) 12 is in maintenance mode now, 14 is active LTS, and 16 will be coming out in April. 14 would be a good version to switch to if you can.

Comment: I will give it an update and try it out! Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Great! That worked for me:

const { myFunction } = await import('../file.mjs')