# How to support es modules and commonjs modules at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some packages we install from npm support both commonjs and es modules,

These packages can be imported as follows:

```js
import express from 'express'
// or
const express = require('express')
```

I have created a package [which I already published to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-player) using es modules.

and I since my another project which I'm working on is built with commonjs, I realized that I can not **require** it using the following syntax:

```js
const stackPlayer = require('stack-player')
```

How can I support the two module systems in my package [stack-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-player) so that everyone around the world can use it?

- Is there another method other than converting all of my project to es modules (which would be too complex since the project is 1 year old and is big enough to refuse the idea). ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [source of express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/442fd467992992558806da8da07e945838712587/lib/express.js#L28) how they did it? You can just use `exports = module.exports = require('./stack-player');`

Comment: @Christopher, it did not work, https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-yy2prn?file=index.js

Comment: *P.S: Your package works with both `import` and `require`. I've tested it.*

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei, no, here's a screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/6D5xwjH/Untitled.png this screenshot is from the sandbox I pasted above

Comment: That is something else and it is a different thing. I mean I've installed your package, and I've tested and it was fine. So if you want to use *ESM* syntaxes, that would be a different thing. You bring up an example from Express, and Express doesn't use ESM syntaxes in their current code.

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei, I want to develop my package in es6 modules, and I want anyone to install it, and `require()` it or `import` it. Of course, it worked with you because it's written in commonjs, I want to re-write it using es6 modules. 

Comment: There's literally thousands of examples on GitHub.

Comment: @morganney  Which of those thousands are good examples and which are bad examples? Which ones use deprecated techniques? In these thousands of examples with thousands of lines, which lines are the ones relevant to the question? How important is it that I use their tools? I could go on, but all of these questions are rhetorical. The point I'm making is, these examples are 99% noise when it comes to answering the question of the OP.

Comment: @DanielKaplan you @ me a year later ¯\_(ツ)_/¯? I don't remember what we were talking about. However, differentiating signal from noise is what distinguishes experience and/or good insight.

Comment: @morganney Since there was no @ in your reply, I thought you were replying to the question. I took it to mean, "Instead of asking, you should find one of the 'literally thousands of examples on GitHub.'" If I misinterpreted your comment, I apologize. But if my interpretation was correct, I wanted to say that this is a good question for SO, IMHO.

Comment: @DanielKaplan no harm no foul. I took a closer look at the post topic and realized what was going on. Anyhow, I've posted an answer that you might find helpful. Happy new year. BTW, I miss the "gourmet ghetto" and all the other fabulous food in your area.

Answer (score 23):

There are two main scenarios:

#### 1. Your package is written using CommonJS (CJS) module loading

This means your package uses `require()` to load dependencies. For this kind of package **no special work is needed to support loading the package in both ES and CJS modules**. ES modules are able to load CJS modules via the `import` statement, with the minor caveat that only default-import syntax is supported. And CJS modules are able to load other CJS modules via the `require()` function. So both ES modules and CJS modules are able to load CJS modules.

#### 2. Your package is written using ES module loading

This means your package uses `import` to load dependencies. But don't be fooled - sometimes, especially when using TypeScript, you may be writing `import` in your code, but it's getting compiled to `require()` behind the scenes.

Unfortunately, CommonJS modules **do not support loading ES modules** except (in Node.js) by using the `import()` function (which is a bit painful and not a great solution).

In order to support CommonJS in this case, your best bet is to transpile your package into a CommonJS module, and ship both CommonJS and ESM versions of your package.

I do this in a [number of my own packages](https://github.com/mistval/unofficial-jisho-api) mostly by using Rollup, which makes it relatively easy.

The basic concept is this:

1. Write your package as an ES module.
2. Install rollup: `npm i -D rollup`
3. Run `npx rollup index.js --file index.cjs --format cjs` to convert your code into a CJS module.
4. Export both from your package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "import": "./index.js",
    "require": "./index.cjs"
  }
}
```

This way, the CJS module loader knows to load your `index.cjs` file, while the ESM loader knows to load your `index.js` file, and both are happy.

Comment: `the CJS module loader knows to load your index.cjs file, while the ESM loader knows to load your index.js file, and both are happy.`  So you are saying if `import` the dependency, some behind the scenes magic is choosing one file instead of the other, and if I use a `require`, different magic picks the cjs file?

Comment: Yes @DanielKaplan when you use `require` and when you use `import` you're running very different code that loads modules in different ways. The CJS module loader will prefer using the `require` field in the module's `package.json`, while the ES module loader will prefer using the `import` field. Keep in mind however the caveat regarding TypeScript, where it's common to write `import` in your TS code, but you have TS configured to compile that to `require` instead. In that case, even though you're writing `import`, `require` is being used and the CJS module loader is being invoked.

Answer (score 8):

### require() Usage

`require()` can, by default, only be used in [CommonJS Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules). The built in method to import ECMAScript modules into CommonJS is using [`import(pathToFile).then(module => { })`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions).

#### Support for require()

If you want to support `require()` for your package, you **must provide** a CommonJS module.

Here's a [functioning example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-3aju8m?file=index.js) that demonstrates when and how to utilize `require()` or `import()`. There are some small differences how `import()` of a CommonJS module works compared to a ECMAScript Module. Especially that only the default property on the module object is available, when `import()` is used on a CommonJS file that exported something with `module.exports`.

`index.js` which imports different module types (from the demo above):
<sup>(In case the stackblitz demo will be deleted:)</sup>

```js
// executed as CommonJS module
console.time('');
import('./lib/example.cjs').then(({ default: example }) => {
  console.timeLog('', 'import cjs', example() == 'Foo'); // true
});
import('./lib/index.mjs').then(({ example }) => {
  console.timeLog('', 'import mjs', example() == 'Foo'); // true
});
try {
  const example = require('./lib/example.cjs');
  console.timeLog('', 'require cjs', example() == 'Foo'); // true
} catch (e) {
  console.timeLog('', 'require cjs', '\n' + e.message);
}
try {
  const example = require('./lib/index.mjs');
  console.timeLog('', 'require mjs', example() == 'Foo');
} catch (e) {
  console.timeLog('', 'require mjs', '\n' + e.message); // Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /path/to/lib/index.mjs not supported.
}
```

`lib/example.cjs`

```js
module.exports = function example() {
  return 'Foo';
};
```

`lib/index.mjs`

```js
import example from './example.cjs';
export { example };
export default example;
```

#### Conditional Export for Packages

A conditional export can be supplied for packages to support `require()`, for example in a case where the CommonJS `require()` is no longer supported by your package. Refer to [this link](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) for more information.

> The "exports" field allows defining the entry points of a package when imported by name loaded either via a node_modules lookup or a self-reference to its own name. It is supported in Node.js 12+ as an alternative to the "main" that can support defining subpath exports and conditional exports while encapsulating internal unexported modules.

`package.json` (example from the nodejs docs)

```json
{
  "exports": {
    "import": "./index-import.js",
    "require": "./index-require.cjs"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

If so, you have to provide two scripts: one for the CommonJS (`"require": "filename"`) and one for the ECMAScript module (`"import": "filename"`).

While `index-require.js` must provide the script via `exports = ...` or `module.exports = ...`, `index-import.js` must provide the script with `export default`.

#### Keyword Usage

You can only use specific keywords depending on the files module type.

###### CommonJS Modules

- `module.exports` is used to define the values that a module exports and makes available for other modules to require. It can be set to any value, including an object, function, or a simple data type like a string or number.
- `exports`, `module`

  - If you use them inside an ECMAScript module you'll get an undefined Error.
- `require()`

  - `require()` inside ECMAScript modules is possible, but you have to use a workaround [as mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784165/10304804) or [take a look at the docs for `module.createRequire(fileName)`](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename):

    ```js
    import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
    const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

    // sibling-module.js is a CommonJS module.
    const siblingModule = require('./sibling-module');
    ```
  - If you call `require()` from within a CommonJS on an ECMAScript module, it throws a not supported Error:

    ```
    Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /path/to/script.mjs not supported.
    ```

    With a more detailed error message depending on the situation:

    > Instead change the require of script.mjs in /path/to/app.js to a dynamic
    > import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

    Or:

    > /path/to/script.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
    >
    > Instead rename /path/to/script.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /path/to/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

###### ECMAScript Moduls (ESM)

- `export default` is used to export a single value as the default export of a module. This allows for a more concise way to import values, as the import statement can omit the curly braces when importing the default export.
- Named exports, on the other hand, allow multiple values to be exported from a module. Named exports use the `export` keyword followed by an identifier and a value. (`export const foo = "bar"`)
- `import ... from ...`

  - It can handle CommonJS files and interprets them as if you would've used `require()`.

    Example based on express:

    ```js
    import express, { Route, Router } from 'express'; // EJS
    // is similar to:
    var express = require("express"), { Route, Router } = express; // CJS
    ```

Both CommonJS and ECMAScript modules support the `import()` function, but the returned object can have more properties on ESM files.

#### Summary:

CJS modules don't need to be converted to ESM, as they can be imported into ESM using the `import ... from ...` syntax without any modifications to the CJS module. However, it's advisable to write new modules using ECMAScript Module syntax, as it is the standard for both web and server-side applications and enables seamless use of the same code on both sides the browser/client-side and node/server-side.

- [Specifications](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules)

Additionally, I find this [article on CommonJS vs. ES modules in Node.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/commonjs-vs-es-modules-node-js/) from logrocket.com to be very informative. It delves into the pros and cons of ECMAScript compared to CommonJS in more depth.

###### Links:

- [MDN: import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)
- [NodeJS.org: Difference between ECMAScript modules and CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#differences-between-es-modules-and-commonjs)

Answer (score 2):

When I'm publishing an npm package with TypeScript, for either node.js or the browser, I use [@knighted/duel](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel) (I am also the author if that matters to you).

It is as easy as creating a `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` with a defined `type` and then defining an npm run script to create a dual build.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**package.json** (`type` of `module` or `commonjs` is ok)

```json
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "duel"
  }
```

```
npm run build
```

Now update the [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) in `package.json` to match the build output in `dist` before you publish.

Comment: How does `duel` solve the dual package hazard?

Comment: [It](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel) delegates [it](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#dual-package-hazard) to the user, i.e. ignores it completely. It exists, and you should know about it. Worry less, produce more.