# why is module.exports glowing red?

Tags: javascript, npm, export

today I started studying the npm, and came across the problem that when declaring the webpack.config.js object, I'm getting an error. As I understand it, it has something to do with the node.js or something like that?

[image]

as I understand there is such a solution, then the linter stops showing the error

[image]

Comment: If your `package.json` is set to `"type": "module"`, `module` isn't support by the Module. You are creating an ESModule. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75347455/10304804) for a better explaination. Changing the entry to `"type": "commonjs"`, may solve this issue but can creates others depending on the other files.