Not able to use CJS(commons) npm package in ESM(type=module) project
I had developed one npm package for my internal use which is written in CommonJS as it uses the express.js so i kept it in common.js
but when i try to import that package in my react.js project along with the VITE it throws the bellow error.
ReferenceError: module is not defined

What i found over the internet that CommonJS packages can work on module.js without any extra configuration but then why i am getting this error.
Note:- I am using npm link to use the package locally but if I install the same package from my private npm repo then it works fine without any error and the source code on both local and live are the same.
Below is the npm package code for how i am exporting the module from the index file.
'use strict'

module.exports = require('./source');

and this is how i am importing it
import {RoutingService} from 'service-provider';

But as discussed above I am getting errors while doing this.
I also heard about the Dual Module Strategy but i don't think it's helpful here if i have a package already in the CommonJS.
Below is my package json.
"name": "service-provider",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "description": "servi e-provider",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./index.js",
      "require": "./index.js"
    }
  },


From the error I can see that the reference to the service-provider is not available. To refer to the package, please follow the below steps

Run 'npm link' command in the service-provider directory.
Run 'npm link service-provider' in your project directory.

By doing this a symlink will get created under the node_modules of the current project to the service-provider package.

it needs to be confirmed that the dual module strategy can solve the problem - provided that the require points to the correct commonjs file and the import points to the correct esmodule file. This actually means you need to package two files.
Your package.json should look similar to:
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "./dist/src/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/src/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./dev": {
      "import": "./src/index.ts",
      "require": "./src/index.ts",
      "types": "./src/index.ts"
    }
  },

If you don't use any packaging tools, it won't work. You need to use rollup or vite to package in lib mode to generate two standard products: commonjs and esmodule.
In cases where the project is not complex, I usually use vite for packaging. You can refer to the document: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

You wrote your package in commonJS and you are trying to import the package in ES module style. Your Vite React app, in the context of ES module as you use import statement to import the npm package, when it encounters module.exports it will fail to understand what is module as module varibale is not initialized in the context of ES module pattern, it is throwing refernce error.
Solution:

Package your npm module either in umd type or esmodule type.
Import package using require().


Well i can definitely not use require() syntax in the es module.
and it is mentioned on this thread that common.js is supported without any modification in the ESM.
-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937600/how-to-support-es-modules-and-commonjs-modules-at-the-same-time

Yes you are right, but in such scenario you should be exporting and importing only default modules not the named modules. "RoutingService" is a named import and it should be default import. Try changing your import to import * as Service from 'service-provider';

I am still getting the same error i tried to export the defaults from the common js package and tried importing using import * syntax but still getting same error.
