# Using webpack and mocha with ES6 modules

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have a frontend JS project. I want to use [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) for testing and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for bundling. I use [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) in my project.

Mocha requires to set the `type` of my package to `module` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/2506522).
While webpack fails in this case with

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'webpack.config.js'
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Invalid host defined options
...
```

How can I use mocha and webpack in an ES6 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Rename `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.cjs`

---

The problem is that webpack [doesn't support ES6 config file](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/282). This means that when you set the `type` of a package to `module` `webpack.config.js` interpreted as an ES6 module, which is not supported yet.

Solutions/workarounds:

1. Set the `type` of a package to `module` and rename `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.cjs` which results that entire your project will interpreted as ES6 modules, except the `webpack.config.cjs` which remains a `commonjs` file.
2. Keep the `type` of a package `commonjs` and rename all of your files to `mjs` (except `webpack.config.js`)
3. Use a different bundler, eg, rollup.