# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" but tsconfig.json `module` already `commonjs`

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, tsconfig

I am somewhat new to typescript, and I am working in a fork of someone else's existing repository, trying to run tests against it.

**Summary**

I have written a test script `examples/test.ts` and am attempting to debug it using the vscode debugger. When I run the script with `ts-node ./examples/test.ts`, the script executes successfully. However, when I try to run it using the vscode debugger, I get the famous `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. This error occurs on line 1 of my typescript test, where I first try to `import {Foo} from '../dist'`, where `Foo` is an object under test.

**Attempted Fixes**

I've been researching for a little while, [the most common fix](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922#issuecomment-765008102) for this seems to be to set `module` to `commonjs` in the `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions`. But, this project already has that set up correctly.

[Another common fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) is to set `"type":"module"` in `package.json`, but when I do that I cause new errors in the vscode debugger. Specifically, `Uncaught TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /path/truncated/by/me/examples/test.ts`. The fact that I can run the script normally outside the debugger makes me think it's more likely to be `tsconfig.json` or similar configuration, of course I may be wrong.

**Relevant config files:**

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/examples/test.ts",
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
        "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "dist",
"strict": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"baseUrl": "./",
"esModuleInterop": true
},
"include": ["*"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**Versions**

Running VSCode 1.52.1 on up-to-date macOS. `ts-node --version` gives `v9.1.1`, and the project uses `node --version` of `v12.14.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem.  Here's what finally worked for my cli project
(using vscode 1.61.2).

**launch.json:**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/cli.ts",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "pwa-node"
    }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "importHelpers": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

**package.json scripts section:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node lib/cli.js",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
```

**package.json devDependencies**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
```