# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (from dependency)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, npm-package

**How do you resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" from a dependency when the dependency isn't declared as a module?**

---

I want to use the [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) in Svelte/kit to validate emails. However, when importing the ESM version, I get the "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error. I'm using pnpm instead of npm or yarn.

```
import isEmail from 'validator/es/lib/isEmail'
```

```
/node_modules/.pnpm/validator@13.6.0/node_modules/validator/es/lib/isEmail.js:1
import assertString from './util/assertString';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at nodeRequire
```

It appears that validator is attempting to use the import statement, but it's package.json does not specify `"type": "module"`. My guess is that this is the root cause of the error.

#### Debug steps

- package.json has `"type": "module"`
- Upgraded to latest version of node
- Tried using the non-esm version of validator `'validator/lib/isEmail'`, but that causes other errors not related to this thread.

#### Related

- [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) — this solution is for code you control, not for dependencies
- ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import) — this seems to be very similar, but I'm getting this error in node, not in the browser

#### Metadata

- Node: v16.2.0
- Sveltekit: v1.0.0-next.115
- Validator: 13.6.0

Comment: Did you restart your editor after setting the `type` property to **`"type": "module"`** in your package.json? If you don't reload the project, intellisense doesn't pickup on it, so things can be working, but intellisense won't be, so it appears as if your doing something wrong, when in fact you are not.

Comment: Just tried, and that doesn't seem to help. This also doesn't seem to be an intellisense issue either. The error occurs when trying to start Sveltekit.

Comment: Have you looked at this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58211880/7416119) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried importing like this?

```
import validator from 'validator'
```

I tried reproducing your issue with latest SvelteKit. This works fine:

```
// index.svelte
<script>
    import validator from 'validator';
    let result = validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com');
    console.log(result);
</script>
```

When I changed the import statement to:

```
import validator from 'validator/es/lib/isEmail'
```

I got the error from your question (Cannot use import statement outside a module).

Importing `validator/es/lib/isEmail` supposedly only imports a subset of the library. I'm not sure how much difference it will make; it might not make any difference. A slightly larger build beats a build that doesn't work. I suggest getting it working first, then optimize the build size if you really need to.

Comment: That works. Interestingly, using a newer version of Svelte/kit, I was able to use `validator/lib/isEmail` as well.

Comment: @Nick Were you able to use it even when building with an adapter? I can use this import when running the svelte-kit development server but when I try to build it for production with the node adapter, I get `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module`

Answer (score 1):

For those that happen to have the same problem while deploying with nodejs using typescript.

`"type":"module"` was already set in my package.json in the main project. I put the build directory on the server (created by `npm run build`).

```
working-dir
  |--build
       |--index.js
       |--...
```

I thought i had to just run `node build/index.js`, as I thought everything was packaged.
Turns out I need to add a **package.json** into the working directory *(I think it also works by putting it into the build directory)*.

```
server
+ |--package.json 
  |--build
       |--index.js
       |--...

// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this

```
import { isEmail } from "validator"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be helping since my code is an ESM module already.

Comment: What errors does the non-esm version give?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, if your problem solely lies in a problem with code you are dependent on, consider short term using something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to make the necessary adjustment, and long term, open up a PR over at the [validator.js repo](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js)!

for patch-package, just go add the `"type": "module"` to the package.json at `node_modules/validator`, and then run `npx patch-package validator`.  You can then version control the outputted diff file, and the changes are made automatically with npm hooks assuming patch-package is a (dev) dependency.

The behavior or defect of the library here is probably from the devs more keeping in mind things like webpack that do esm imports on their own terms, and not with the node module resolution patterns that it appears svelte is using. or at least how the problem has gotten this far.(might be wrong about this!).

Answer (score 0):

After reading their docs: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#es6, it looks like the `es` part in the import is, so it can be treeshakable. You can fix this error, by just importing it normally:

```
import isURL from 'validator/lib/isURL';
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to import like below

```
const {isEmail} = require('validator');
```

Comment: Nice idea, but SvelteKit doesn't have access to `require`