# How do I generate static HTML for my homepage from Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, react-app-rewired, static-site-generation

I have a CRA and want to have the first page generated statically to improve load time and SEO. The idea is to run a NodeJS script that renders the App document inside index.html.

Here is my code:

```html
const { renderToString } = require("react-dom/server");
const App = require('./App');
const content = `<html><body>${renderToString(App)}</body></html>`
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('../public/index.html', content);
```

However, I have problems running it with NodeJS:

```
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Apparently, I have to build the source, but I don't know how to do it. I'm using CRA to build my React files (actually, I'm using react-app-rewired, so I could customize the build process if I only knew how to do it).

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

the error is from node: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/13216797

I know it's not your question... but what about using Nextjs?

Even without a node environment you can use the [`"next export"`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) command to make a bundle that will work as it would static files while still being react...

Comment: I know about NextJS but I have a pretty big project in production already and I can't just rewrite it with NextJS. Next time I'll be wiser.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using puppeteer and just saving the generated client-side code. Before that I spent hours stubbing out first `window`, then `window.location`, then `window.localStorage`, `window.document`, `window.document.createElement`, it never ended. With puppeteer, it was pretty easy.