# How to set up the preact-render-to-string on the express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, preact

Please tell me how to set up the [preact-render-to-string](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-render-to-string) on the [express](https://expressjs.com/).

- https://github.com/preactjs/preact-render-to-string#render-jsx--preact--whatever-via-express
- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

I built it reading the above links. The source code is on [there](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-render-to-string#render-jsx--preact--whatever-via-express), but I'm not used to `node`
I don't know how to execute it(Or I don't know if I'm failing to build the environment.).

I believe my installation procedure can be found in `package.json`(`dependencies` and `devDependencies`). So, below is my `package.json`.

**My package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.5.14",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.19"
  }
}
```

**My app.js** (Same as [Document](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-render-to-string#render-jsx--preact--whatever-via-express)):
I didn't know what to do with the file name, so I used `app.js`.

```
import express from 'express';
import { h } from 'preact';
import render from 'preact-render-to-string';
/** @jsx h */

// silly example component:
const Fox = ({ name }) => (
    <div class="fox">
        <h5>{ name }</h5>
        <p>This page is all about {name}.</p>
    </div>
);

// basic HTTP server via express:
const app = express();
app.listen(8080);

// on each request, render and return a component:
app.get('/:fox', (req, res) => {
    let html = render(<Fox name={req.params.fox} />);
    // send it back wrapped up as an HTML5 document:
    res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>${html}</body></html>`);
});
```

**Run and Error**:

```
$ node app.js  
src/pr/ex/app.js:1
import express from 'express';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I think I am running it wrong or failed to build the environment, what can I do to make it run successfully?

`node` is installed with `nodebrew`. The current status is as follows.

```
$ nodebrew list
v16.6.2

current: v16.6.2
```

**Edit:**

I tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/1979953).

> add the top-level "type" field with a value of "module"

The error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` is gone and **different error** occurred.

```
$ node app.js   
file:///src/pr/ex/app.js:8
    <div class="fox">
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:146:18)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)
```

Since I am using [preact](https://preactjs.com/) (I must be using [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm) internally), it is odd that `Unexpected token '<'` would be an error.

`package.json` after editing:

```
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.5.14",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: "I must be using HTM internally" Sorry, I don't follow. You're definitely not using HTM, but you're authoring in JSX. You need to run your app through Babel (which is what that JSX comment is for at the top of the file).

Comment: It was JSX? If so, I must have been mistaken. I know about Babel itself, but I don't know how to run it. Can you please help me?

Comment: I always use Babel with a framework like NextJS or a CDN, so I don't know how to use it with this question.

Comment: Yes, that component is JSX. `<div>...</div>` is not valid JS, hence the error being thrown. You can look up how to use Babel with Express (there's plenty of full examples out there) or switch to using HTM, which doesn't need to be transpiled.

Comment: When I used `preact-cli` in other directory, Bable and HTM were working without my awareness. For this reason, I thought it would compile on `import render from 'preact-render-to-string';`, but it seems to be different, so I will look into it.

Comment: Preact-CLI doesn't use HTM. An import statement doesn't transpile the file. It just gives you access to exported members from that module.

Comment: I see. I guess I misunderstood a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Use require:

```
const express = require('express')
const { h } = require('preact')
```

2. Save your app.js file as a .mjs file (Node13+ only)
3. Add { type: 'module' } in your package.json