# nuxt.config.js cannot use import statement outside a module, import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to deploy function only to firebase, here is the error:

```
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

C:\Users\User\Documents\someapps\functions\nuxt.config.js:1
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
```

The main error is: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Important part of the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        light: {
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `colors` used by `vuetify` config among others, how to refactor `import colors` without error?

### I've tried:

Transpile like the documentation [suggest](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins) :

```
build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify/es5/util/colors'],
}
```

The error changed to `ReferenceError: colors is not defined` since I dunno where/how to define the `colors` without the `import`.

Comment: Do you need to add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`?

Comment: @Andy I don't think editing ```package.json``` can alleviate the error.

Comment: It was just a thought as I had the same issue (although not Vue-related) come up a couple of days ago.

Comment: Can you follow [this StackOverFlow  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717) and [this github issue comment](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/101#issuecomment-568258910) to see if it works for you? Also can you run `npm update vuetify` to upgrade vuetify and see if it resolves the error?

Comment: Tried [that StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717) the `"type": "module"`, not working. In my case the module is not missing, so I skip the github issue comment link. For now I settle without the `import` line and declare all the value needed inside the `export default`, and move on :)

Comment: Does that mean you are not getting the error anymore?

Comment: No error, because I remove `import colors...` line.