# How to use libraries in a node js project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know what I'm doing. I don't understand why it shows me the following errors. First of all, I want to say that I've searched for info and self explain videos but I can't solve this error.
So I want to create a `node js` project. For that, I use `npm init` and set `app.mjs` as my script. Then, I do `npm install axios` and go live in a local server. I write in `app.mjs` the following line to follow `ES6` module codetype but I get this error in the console:

```
import axios from 'axios'
// Error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`. I've tried to use `require` replacing`.js` too but it doesn't work neither.

What I'm doing wrong? Furthermore, to not having the same error, how am I supposed to do it in a corrrect way in my future projects?

**EDIT: Adding package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "app.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: @ponury-kostek no sorry it doesn't. I've tried its answers but I can't solve it

Comment: You don't use `require` in a `"type": "module"` project, you use `import axios from "axios";` That's what that the duplicate is getting at.

Comment: @zero298 I have that `"type": "module"` with `import axios from 'axios';`. I was just saying that i tried with require

Comment: Can you show the `package.json`?

Comment: @beto i've added it on the main question

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error. I'm on node 14.16.1

Comment: i'm on version v14.17.3