# dateformat npm package giving error on node server restart

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install

I am using dateformat npm package of version 4.5.1 and getting error on server restart as

```
server must be sue import to load ES module
usr/src/app/nodemodules/dateformat/lib/dateformat.js | require() ES module is not supported
```

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error while using the `dateformat` package. Then tried a different version which is dateformat@4.6.3 and it worked!

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
npm i dateformat@4.6.3
```

Example code:

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `package.json` file. You need to import statement instead of require.
Or else try this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30649304)