# How to handle TS library w/import used by React and Express apps?

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, transpiler

I have a monorepo that includes both a front-end (CRA) React app and an Express API.  They both use another package in the monorepo that is plain TS, but uses `import` statements.  I use `tsc` to compile the TS -> JS for the React app, into a directory I call `tscompiled`, and for the Node app I further transpile the JS with babel to a directory called `lib`, so that all the `import` statements become `require`s.

So when I want to compile the React app, I need `package.json` for my dependency to use the `tscompiled` directory with its type definitions:

```
"main": "tscompiled/index.js",
```

And then when I want to compile the Express app, I need `package.json` for my dependency to use the `lib` directory:

```
"main": "lib/index.js",
```

This is a real kludge — can I get my Node Express app to handle `import` statements or transpile dependent packages within the monorepo automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `imports` if you configure your project correctly. See the solutions mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module).

Comment: This has gotten me a certain part of the way there, but I'm running up against a new problem — I use require for a number of json files, but once I set `"type": "module"`, I can't use require.  Yet as far as I can tell import for json files is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for this problem, which was to use webpack for my Express API, with babel taking care of compiling TS and transpiling ES in dependent modules.

`.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx|jsx|js)x?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.helpers.js'],
        mainFields: ['main'],
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
}
```