# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when setting up socket.io in adonisjs

Tags: javascript, import, async-await, socket.io, adonis.js

am following [socketio with adonisjs](https://docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/socketio-with-adonisjs) to be able to implement web sockets but I get
this error

```
[ info ]  building project...
[ info ]  starting http server...

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

at /home/../providers/AppProvider.ts(anonymous):18
13    }
14  
15    public async ready () {
16      // App is ready
17      if (this.app.environment === 'web') {
18        await import('../start/socket')
19  
20      }
21    }
22  
23    public async shutdown () {

[ encore ] Running webpack-dev-server ...
[ warn ]  Underlying HTTP server died with "0 code"
```

when I try out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/6842763) of adding `"type": "module",` to package.json I get other errors

how can I fix this?

Comment: can you share more code ?

Comment: Do you want to see what is in start/socket.js

Comment: where do you import the socket io module?

Comment: in `app/Services/Ws.ts` just like [this says](https://docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/socketio-with-adonisjs). I tried adding code and it's too much for the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using a `start/socket.js` instead of `start/socket.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "name": "socket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

Check your package.json file,  "type": "module" is missing , Make sure to add this as shown in this one !!!