# Unable to use wallpaper module with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm having issues with the wallpaper module in nodejs.

I run the install with npm, in the dir that contains my code :
`npm i wallpaper -g` .

I don't have any error after that but I cannot use the module.
When I'm trying to run the script with `node myprgrm.js`

I get the following error : `Cannot find module 'wallpaper' from '/path/'  in /path/myprgrm.js`

Did somone have an idea why ?

EDIT 1 :

After installing wallpaper without `-g`, it created `package-lock.json`, the same apply for `npm i wallpaper --save`.

I get the following error :

```
(node:4252) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/path/myprgrm.js:1
import {getWallpaper, setWallpaper} from 'wallpaper';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

So I try to replace my package.json by package-lock.json but, still the same error.

And I don't really know how to preicsely manipulate .json

Thanks

Edit 2 :

I find the answer over here : [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module?rq=1)

Comment: `-g` installs it globally. Try removing that

Comment: npm i wallpaper --save