# How to use import with existing Node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

With Node 16.13.2 I am trying to add the [validate module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate) in an existing code base. Reading the [2 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58384179/314813) I can't make it work with the below PoC. I get

```
import Schema from 'validate';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

**Question**

Can anyone show me how the below PoC should look like for it to work?

**index.js**

```
const mod = require('./mod');
```

**mod.js**

```
import Schema from 'validate';

const test;
module.exports = test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `import` syntax of `es6+` then you will either need to use `.mjs` files (instead of regular `.js` files), or you will need to add in a compilation/transpilation step into your pipeline.

### Using `.mjs`

If you change the file name of your `mod.js` file to `mod.mjs`, then this should work:

```
import Schema form 'validate';
export const test;
```

Then in `index.js` you will either have to change `index.js` to `index.mjs` and change the contents to:

```
import { test } from './mod.mjs';
```

..or you can keep `index.js` and change the contents to:

```js
(async () {
  const { test } = await import('./mod.mjs')
})();
```

You can read more in this rather comprehensive article i happened across while googling: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-ecmascript-modules-with-node-js/

### Adding a compilation step

There are many different compilers and/or bundlers to pick from, but for regular vanilla javascript I'd recommend sticking to [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Freecodecamp has a tutorial for how to set up babel for use with nodejs: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setup-babel-in-nodejs/

Comment: Thnaks a lot. Is there a simpler solution if I don't want to use `import`?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting assuming the library you are trying to import is [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate), then you should be able to simple require it as normal. `const Schema = require("validate")`