# Typescript SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (side file containing functions)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I am creating a minecraft bot using [mineflayer](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/) library. After a bit of work I decided to make code readable and reusable ([image of file organisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znX0E.png)) and also start using typescript. I  have read a lot of stack threads and other articles as this problem is quite popular. However, after trying all of it the problem still persists.

## Edit, important change:

I have tried compiling it with `tsc bot.ts --resolveJsonModule` and then `node bot.js`. It turns out it works just fine, so now the problem narrows down to configuring [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) running options.

#### Here is what I have already done

- package.json `"type": "module` -> `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for` *path*
- tsconfig.json **has** `"esModuleInterop": true`
- use `const util = require('./utils/util')` and use `util.function()` -> same error as in *1st* step

#### Running whole code

As I am using WebStorm, this is what I have in running options: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiGoh.png) (just to clarify that I don't run code from terminal)

#### Recreating problem in simplified environment

*bot.ts*

```
import {util} from "./utils/util" // error is thrown right away, so other lines are irrelevant I guess

const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const bot = mineflayer.createBot()
```

*util.ts*

```
import * as config from "../config/config_main.json"
export module util {
    export function sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

    export function random(list) {
        if (list[0] === list[1]) return list[0];
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (list[1] - list[0]))  + list[0];
    }
}
```

*config_main.json*

```json
{
  "bot": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                           
  }
}
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "mcbot",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "None"
  }
}
```

#### Related threads

- [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) - `"type": "module"` doesn't work as well as changing extensions to `.mjs` isn't viable as I am using typescript
- ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import) - from here tried

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
parse = require('node-html-parser');
```

but the IDE gives me `TS2632: Cannot assign to 'util' because it is an import.` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixed by changing:

```js
import {util} from "./utils/util"
```

#### To:

```js
const util = require('./utils/util')
// or
const { sleep, random, eatAny, clickItem, lookAtEntity} = require('./utils/util')
```

Afterall I don't know why compiling with `tsc` had been working well while webstorm was throwing out error. I just changed the `import` *ES6* syntax to `require()` *CommonJS*.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove `type:module` from package.json. Then remove `module:commonjs` from tsconfig.json. Use `export default function util () {}`  syntax. Named exports will also work for local files if you've done the first two steps.

#### Cause

You are mixing es6 and commonjs. `module:commonjs` is forcing it to be commonjs whereas `esModuleInterop` is forcing it to be es6. And `type:module`shows error for es6 and forces to write file extension, remove it first

#### Warning

Named imports will not work for npm package. Like you can't use

`import { something } from "some-package";`

Instead, import the default one and then access the named one.

`import defaultExport from "some-package";`

`const something = defaultExport.something`

Comment: Okay so I did what you told me to do:

| change to `module util{} ... export default util` and `export default function something() {}`

| using `import util from "./utils/util"`

| `"type": "module"` was already deleted because it wasn't warning //package.json

| deleted `"module": "commonjs"` //tsconfig.ts

now pops up: `Error:(5, 5) TS5070: Option '--resolveJsonModule' cannot be specified without 'node' module resolution strategy.` -> So I tested with "moduleResolution": "node" and similar to 1st error comes out: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: I.E. I did exactly what you told me to do and the SyntaxError still persists. If it would be helpful, here's my *whole* mcbot directory: 
[bot.ts](https://pastebin.com/wfPuF3CW) |
[util.ts](https://pastebin.com/VgmuFVyJ) |
[attack.ts](https://pastebin.com/KwVjb5YF) | 
[movement.ts](https://pastebin.com/31chYKZn) |
[config_main.json](https://pastebin.com/Djps3XFV) |
[tsconfig.json](https://pastebin.com/uwrzfyE2) |
[package.json](https://pastebin.com/yT45975v) 

**Every pastebin file is protected by password** `stackoverflow`

Comment: **Important note:** when compiling in cmd terminal with `tsc bot.ts --resolveJsonModule` in `mcbot` directory and then running it with `node bot.js`, everything works **just fine**.

Comment: @jancor When you are using `tsc bot.ts` this command ignores tsconfig file. You should rather run only `tsc`. [Here](https://temp.sh/dzMLO/mcbot.zip) I've uploaded the zipped file. Unzip it, go to unzipped directory do a `npm i` and then run `tsc`

Comment: Thank you @KasRoudra for your help. I've unzipped the dir you sent, ran `npm i` & `tsc` and after that, `node bot.js` to test if it works, and well, it does. However, this issue jumps back to WebStorm, because although I can run it with those commands, I can't run it from WebStorm, which is essential for me as I find it very convenient. I opened that directory as a project in WS, created configuration file for running: added config for node.js -> assigned `bot.ts` to `JavaScript file` -> added before-launch param `Compile TypeScript` and used the tsconfig.json file for it -> saved and ran:

Comment: `C:\Users\jasiu\Desktop\mcbot_v2\bot.ts:1` \n `import mineflayer from "mineflayer";
` \n `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Nothing changed besides the fact that now it's a `mineflayer` import, not my own `util` module.