# How can I run a standalone script within a next.js project?

Tags: next.js

Within a next.js project, I wish to run a standalone script written in typescript. This script needs to import various source files in my next.js project but it just performs some database queries and writes some output to stdout so it doesn't need to start a webserver or anything like that. What is the best way to do this?

If I just run `node myscript.js` then I get a ton of import errors, presumably because my typescript code is not directly parseable by node.

What is the canonical way to run a standalone script in a next.js project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) package to run your script.
It runs out of the box with NextJS, with both JavaScript and TypeScript.

Install with:

```
npm install --save-dev tsx
```

Declare your script in `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "my-js-script": "tsx scripts/my-script.js",
  "my-ts-script": "tsx scripts/my-script.ts"
},
```

Run it:

```
npm run my-js-script
npm run my-ts-script
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74669154/1273077