# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - Firebase with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

Node.js Code I have in index.js

```
let express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

let app = express()
const port = 8080
app.get('/updateRelay/:relayId/:status', function (req, res) {
    const relayId = req.params["relayId"]
    const status = req.params["status"]
    console.log(relayId,status)
    let updateObject = {}
    updateObject[relayId] = status
    database.ref("iot-device-001/status").set(updateObject, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            // The write failed...
            console.log("Failed with error: " + error)
        } else {
            // The write was successful...
            console.log("success")
        }
    })
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I cannot for the love of God figure out what is wrong with this code. I have tried every documentation and tutorial available and end up with some unexplainable error. Its either this or its Module Not Found. [Here](https://dev.to/irohitgaur/how-to-use-firebase-realtime-database-in-a-node-js-app-nn) is the link for the tutorial I followed which gave me Module Not Found error

Here is the error I have right now

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Did you mark your package.json with `"type": "module"`?  See [Modules: CommonJS modules > Enabling](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#enabling)

Comment: If i do that, im unable to require express. Is it not possible to use both express and firebase in a single js file and run it as a webserver? @Wyck

Comment: See this answer to [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61947868/1563833)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your function is not defined as being a module so you can't use `import`inside of it. You'll have to use `require`

You might solve your issue by replacing

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
```

by

```
var initializeApp = require('firebase/app')
var getDatabase = require('firebase/database')
```

You will find more explanation here : https://flexiple.com/javascript-require-vs-import/

Comment: Now I get this error, `TypeError: initializeApp is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

It is often a bit confusing how to implement it from Node JS. The easiest way is to follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for the installation in NodeJS, once the [SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk) is installed in your local project it is necessary to [initialize it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk).

[For that, you should follow the instructions to generate a Private key that you have to add to your project to call the services from it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OmAz.png)

*Even so, it is still a bit confusing but I found a very simple [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6KJ7FSMifw) that explains in a visual and detailed way how to do it.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me, replace

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
```

with

```
var {initializeApp} = require('firebase/app')
var {getDatabase} = require('firebase/database')
```