# nodejs / import modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't get the logic of the module conception in nodejs / javascript

Here is my file : circle.js

```
const circleArea = r => 3.14 * (r ** 2);
const squareArea = s => s * s;
export {circleArea, squareArea};
```

file testCircle.js

```
import { circleArea as circle, squareArea } from "./circle.js"
console.log(squareArea(2));
```

When I run the program node testCircle.js

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I have found an explanation here :

[SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

So In have updated my package.json

```
  "type": "module"
```

And it works

BUT

then when I want to run another file which require :

```
const http = require("http");
```

I got this new error :

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Is there a way to work with both import and require ?

Comment: Just use import instead of require.

Comment: Can you remove `type="module"` from 'package.json` and try again ?

Comment: @Jaood_xD Your comment is wrong and the link doesn't even mention ES6 modules.

Comment: An example for a ES6 module importing an CJS module: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dar2r5?file=index.js

Comment: @jabaa my bad, wrong link

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension `mjs` for ES6 modules without `"type": "module"` or `cjs` for Common JS modules with `"type": "module"`. Then you can use both types of modules in one project.

Example 1:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "node-starter",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

`index.js`:

```
import { a } from './a.cjs';

a();
```

`a.cjs`:

```
module.exports = {
  a() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
  },
};
```

Running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dar2r5

Example 2:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "node-starter",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.mjs"
  }
}
```

`index.mjs`:

```
import { a } from './a.js';

a();
```

`a.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  a() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
  },
};
```

Running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-enengw

Comment: If I add `const http = require("http")` in your index.mjs, then I got an error : _ReferenceError: require is not defined_

Comment: @fransua A file is either a CommonJS module or a ES6 module. You can't use `require` in a ES6 module and you can't use `import` in a CommonJS module. That means you can't mix `require` and `import` in the same file. Use `import http from "http";` instead