# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module | on android :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, babeljs

I am trying to upgrade my project from RN v0.61.4 to v0.63.4.
I am able to run debug builds on android but release builds are throwing 1 error in gradle task `:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Stacktrace

```
(node:77926) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/MyProject/android/react-native/node_modules/react-native/index.js:13
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1117:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1165:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My project structure is a bit different from usual. As the react native root folder lies inside android root folder. I have made necessary changes in app/build.gradle to handle that.

I even tried creating a fresh project with similar structure as mine and I am still getting this issue.

Attaching minimum reproducible code for the same.

[Sample Project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqF8p8DKKlxBnLw30Rmdgo3lwJH_SA)

Steps to reproduce

```
cd react-native
npm i
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. It was the CLI path that was wrong in `app/build.gradle`
replaced

```
cliPath : "node_modules/react-native",
```

with

```
cliPath : "node_modules/react-native/cli.js",
```

Comment: Fresh react native installs (0.70.X) don't even have this value in `app/build.gradle`...

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have the latest version of Node.js installed (or, at least 13.2.0+).

> The main reason behind getting this error is that we have used the ES6 feature for importing our module but our NodeJS package.json doesn’t know about it. All we need to do is to set our type module in our package.json file.

In your `package.json` file, you should try:

```
{
    ...
    "type" : "module"
    ...
}
```

E.g.:

[image]

If that doesn't work:

Explicitly name files with the `.mjs` extension. All other files, such as `.js` will be interpreted as CommonJS, which is the default if `type` is not defined in `package.json`.

Relevant sources:

- [Codesource.io](https://codesource.io/how-to-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-nodejs/)
- [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: This is happening in node_module/react-native package. I don't think modifying its package.json is the solution here. Babel should take care of this but somehow its not working.

Comment: Try my second option? Thanks for informing me that it doesn't work! :3 @Rishabh876