# how to call functions from an npm package I wrote

Tags: node.js, npm, packaging

sorry this is a very basic question. I wrote some functions to handle requests by passing a callback to `http.createServer`. The functions work if I import them directly from the functions.js file like in this code.

```
import {handle_request} from './functions.js';
import http from 'http';

http.createServer(handle_request).listen(8080);
```

Now I want to put this in a package, so that I can install the libraries my code depends on automatically with npm install. My `package.json` looks like this, I can install the package and I's found in the node REPL, but how do I actually call the functions in the package or use them as callbacks?

```
{
  "name": "package_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "posts images to a slack channel",
  "main": "functions.js",
  "author": "me",
  "dependencies": {
    "mustache": "*"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

The functions are defined like this:

```
export var handle_request = function (req, res) {
// function body ...
}
```

I think my problem is either the import statements in the script that calls the library or some missing exports in the package.

Sorry again for the very basic question, I found many posts and documentations on npm packages but nothing solving my problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `import {handle_request} from 'package_name';`

Comment: I want to use this in a script outside of the package. If I use this syntax I get "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Now I get `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module [...]/functions.js from [...]/app/start_server.js not supported.
Instead change the require of functions.js in [...]/app/start_server.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

(I have other imports inside functions.js, can this be a problem, if I'm mixing import mechanisms)

Comment: See the examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: Thank you @HeikoTheißen I found what I was missing in the MDN article. Import gives a promise to the module not the module itself, with `let module_name = await import("module_name");` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution for sake of completeness. There were two mistakes I made:

1. there's a difference between import mechanisms inside and outside of a module context. The script calling the functions is not inside the module, therefore a using dynamic import is more appropriate.
2. dynamic import returns a promise, which I missed on an earlier try. In my case this is only called before the server starts, so I can just wait for the promise to be evaluated.

What worked in the end was:

```
let package_name = await import("package_name");
```

Thanks for the comment with the link to mdn, this helped a lot.