# Does Netbeans have Maven built-in?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have Netbeans 7.2 installed on my system and use it to load some Java-based projects..
I use Maven for the build and have pom.xml file as part of my added project.

When I right click on my project in Netbeans and do "Clean and Build", my project compiles and I get the output artifact correctly.

My question is I have not downloaded/installed Maven explicitly..so how is Netbeans able to compile my project successfully...Does it have Maven built-in OR does it get it from somewhere online?

Comment: The Netbeans documentation answered that question in less than 10 seconds for me: https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/tools.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it has one version built in, but you can change the maven home directory in the options, if you like to change the version:

Tools -> Options -> Java -> Maven

Comment: Thx a lot for that...
I know u have answered the main question...But could u briefly also explain about the Project Properties...mainly the Actions tab in Netbeans under Properties...

Comment: I think this is briefly already explained in an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458928/netbeans-7-1-invoking-actions-other-than-build-and-clean-build