# How can I speed up maven builds of JavaFX application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans, javafx

My problem can be reproduced by creating a new project in Netbeans 8:

New Project >> Maven >> JavaFX Application

Then adding the org.springframework spring-context dependency.

Build times go up from a few seconds to more than half a minute, most of it due to running javafxpackager.

I can live with slow release builds but how can I speed up my development builds?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mavenproject1</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>Your Organisation</name>
</organization>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-createjar</argument>
                            <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                            <argument>-appclass</argument>
                            <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                            <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                            <argument>-outdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                            <argument>-outfile</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>  
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks! 
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the plugin in a profile that is inactive by default. Then, in order to make the production build, you would have to manually specify the activation of that profile (or [activate](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) it in any other standard way).

You pom would be something like (only diffs shown):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                ...
                <executions>
                    <!-- take this out of here
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        ...
                    </execution>
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        ...
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>javafxpackager</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- INSERT THE exec-maven-plugin HERE, ONLY
                         WITH THE unpack-dependencies EXECUTION -->
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

In production run `mvn ... -Pjavafxpackager`

Comment: Thanks Nikos, this did the trick. Using the maven-assembly-plugin I was able to generate an executable jar file for normal builds.

Answer (score 3):

To complete Nikos' answer, this is the configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin which creates the archive for normal builds.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration> 
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>my-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>assembly</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

above solutions dont work. The problem has nothing to do with javafxpackager whatsoever. The cause lies in the maven standard configuration. On every project run Maven performs a project clean by default. This deletes the targets/classes/ folder. Thats the same folder where all the unpacked jar files of your dependencies are placed. If those get deleted on every new run then they have to be unpacked over and over again. Anyway, heres how you can prevent the clean from happening:

```
    <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Add this to your POM.xml. Make sure you get the version correct You can check the version of your maven clean plugin in the effective pom (thats parent pom + project POM combined). In netbeans you can watch the readonly effective pom.xml under the effective tab when you've opened the pom.xml file of your project.

please give me a few +1's i want to get 50 points so that i can finally comment on other peoples answers. Thank you!

EDIT:

Also add skip to default-cli to avoid errors

```
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                                <skip>true</skip>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

EDIT 2:

For those of you who would like to retain the ability to clean heres another method to prevent the maven plugin from deleting all jar files:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
    <filesets>
        <!-- delete directories that will be generated when you 
             start the develpment server/client in eclipse  
        -->
        <fileset>
            <directory>target/classes</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>
```

Again, make sure  is correct

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

To avoid unpacking dependencies, you don't need to modify the default pom.xml at all. Just change what Netbeans calls when you press Run (or Debug). In nbactions.xml change:

- **runfx.args**: Replace `-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"` with `-cp %classpath ${mainClass}`. This way, the `exec` goal will not try to execute any jar but rather run your project from the `target/classes` directory. So no need to build the jar at all.
- **goals**: replace the "package" goal with "process-classes" (or "test" or any phase you want). We don't need a jar so no need to run the package phase. And no package phase also means no unpacking/repacking etc.

If you ever need the jar file with all the dependencies, just choose "clean and build" in Netbeans or run `mvn clean install`.

**Background:**

What happens when you press run in the standard Netbeans JavaFX maven project is:

- clean package exec - defined in nbactions.xml, configured in pom.xml:

  - clean: as usual - deletes the target directory
  - package:

    - first as usual - copies resources and compiles sources to target/classes and packs that all to a jar without dependencies
    - maven-dependency-plugin unpacks all the dependency jar files to target/classes
    - exec-maven-plugin:unpack-dependencies (the id "unpack-dependencies" is missleading, should be something like "jar-with-dependencies") executes javapackager which builds a jar with dependencies overwriting the first jar
  - exec:

    - executes java with ${runfx.args} as arguments (defined in nbactions.xml) i.e. runs the jar

What happens after the changes above:

- clean process-classes exec - defined in nbactions.xml, configured in pom.xml:

  - clean: as usual - deletes the target directory
  - process-classes:

    - as usual - copies resources and compiles sources to target/classes
  - exec:

    - executes java with ${runfx.args} as arguments (defined in nbactions.xml) i.e. runs the class target/classes/path/to/your/MainClass

**Even better:**

You may want remove the "clean" goal from nbactions.xml. This way, all the resource files won't be copied each time over and over (although the resource plugin will still keep saying "Copying X resources" - see the comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700970/3519572).

Now, you may also want to only recompile changed classes rather than the whole project by adding `useIncrementalCompilation=false` (e.g. like `<goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec -Dmaven.compiler.useIncrementalCompilation=false</goal>`). But be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/49700942/3519572!

Therefore, you may also want to add a toolbar button to the "clean" goal to be able to run it manually easily at any time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26546551/3519572.

**BTW:**

Finally, you might want to change the NetBeans generated pom.xml anyway. At least my NB 8.2 refers to the deprecated javafxpackager (rename to javapackager). Also the part `<bootclasspath>..../lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>` doesn't seem to be necessary with java 8. It actually breaks my build if I run it from the terminal. Removing it seems to fix it and doesn't seem to cause any trouble if started from NB.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use parallel maven build feature to speed up.

By default, Maven does not utilize the full power of your hardware. It builds all modules sequentially rather than in parallel. However, often your project setup does not require it to be sequential. Often you can command Maven to analyze your project including the dependency graph and build the project in parallel where possible. You can either specify the exact number of threads to use for building your project or use a portable version of the parameter and specify the number of thread in terms of CPUs available on the machine.

```
mvn -T 4 install -- will use 4 threads
mvn -T 1C install -- will use 1 thread per available CPU core
```

See for more details: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-maven-build-is-slow-speed-it-up/