# How to stop Maven from overwriting resource files

Tags: java, maven, incremental-build

I have the default maven structure:

```
main
--java
--resources
--webapp
```

I see that every `mvn compile` copies resources even though they were not changed.
What should I do to make build copy only changed files?

```
<build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.resources.overwrite>false</maven.resources.overwrite>
    </properties>
```

Here is the output in debug mode:

```
[INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
directory C:\core\src\main\resources
excludes []
includes []
[DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
[INFO] Copying 190 resources
[DEBUG] file batch.bat has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\core\src\main\resources\batch.bat to C:\core\target\classes\batch.bat
[DEBUG] file DataObject.hbm.xml has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\core\src\main\resources\com\data\DataObject.hbm.xml to C:\core\target\classes\com\data\DataObject.hbm.xml
```

Comment: Could you post your POM file? Maven should not overwrite the resources if they haven't changed.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm suffering from same problem. maven resources plugin always copies my src/main/resources/application.properties. overwrite=false did not work. It results in creating new jar file again, so new docker image created, and so docker service has to pull new image, even if there is no change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the property `-Dmaven.resources.overwrite=false` on the Maven command. See the `overwrite` parameter of the [`resources:resources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) goal.

However the documentation mentions this is the default behavior so check if this parameter is set to true somewhere in your project configuration.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, it seems that even though the log indicates copying, in fact the files are not being changed (the timestamps remain the same when `maven.resources.overwrite` is false).

Comment: thanks, I tried setting a maven property, no luck. Is that what you mean? <properties>
        <maven.resources.overwrite>false</maven.resources.overwrite>
    </properties>

Comment: @lili Yes you can do this or just `-Dmaven.resources.overwrite=false` via the command line. Did you check if the file was actually modified (with a newer last modified timestamp)? Maybe the debug output is not significant here.

Comment: thats an interesting idea. how can I see if its copying the file or just writing the log? If I delete one of the files, it appears in the target folder again

Comment: @lili Don't delete the file: of course in this case it will copy it again. Just keep it and see on the second run if the last modified time of the file is changed. Use the `dir` command on Windows or `ll` on Unix.

Comment: the last modified date does not change, because the file is copied (its not touched)

Comment: @lili Not true. Did you try switching the property to true to see the difference in the timestamp?

Comment: sorry, you are right. changing the flag to true updates the timestamp

Comment: @manouti Thanks! Although the answer is old, you might want to modify it so that it contains the information from your comments. Especially the point that the files are not actually copied even if the plugin says "Copying X resources".

Answer (score 4):

Be aware:

The `maven-resources-plugin` ignores the `overwrite` flag if `filtering` resources is activated.

Answer (score 1):

using version `3.2.0` I had to add the following to make it work:

```
<configuration>
  <useBuildFilters>false</useBuildFilters>
  <overwrite>false</overwrite>
  ...
</configuration>
```

see also [maven-resources-plugin docu](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html)

## likely background:

since filtering is enabled by default, it may not know if the potentially contained properties for filtering have changed and thus overwrites (ignores the implicit `overwrite:false`.
disabling the filtering is thus needed and additionally with the version above I had to explicitely turn overwrite off. :-/
inconsistent docu, I would say.